# How do I turn a String into a InputStreamReader in java?

Tags: java, string, stream

How can I transform a `String` value into an `InputStreamReader`?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

[ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) also does the trick:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( myString.getBytes( charset ) );
```

Then convert to reader:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Comment: You might *want* to inherit the platform's default charset.

Comment: Thanks. Done. What's the best way to detect the plataform's default charset ?

Comment: Or just use getBytes() without a parameter... Arguably it should not exist, but it will use the default encoding.

Comment: [`ByteArrayInputStream `](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html): **Since:**  JDK1.0   There’s not the slightest reason to assume that this class is “since Java 1.4”. That wrong version number is especially weird as Java 1.4 introduced `NIO` and it makes little sense to introduce an API and its conceptional successor within the same version.

Answer (score 64):

I also found the apache commons `IOUtils` class , so :

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(myString));
```

Comment: Converting String->byte[] or vice versa without mentioning a character encoding is almost always a bug.

Comment: This may cause data loss, depending on the default platform encoding and characters in the string. Specifying a Unicode encoding for both encoding and decoding operations would be better. Read this for more details: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_lossyconversions

Comment: Isn't the encoding param just needed to get bytes in a certain encoding? I think as long as you pick the same encoding for the String#getBytes call as you pick for the InputSTreamReader constructor, it doesn't really matter which one you pick. I am pretty sure that Joachim and McDowell are wrong for this specific case. No encoding knowledge needed for wrapping an InputStreamReader around a String.

Comment: @Stijn de Witt - belated reply I know, but I just saw this. If the default platform encoding does not support the code points in the string, data loss will result. If your default encoding is UTF-8, no problem. If you're running on Windows, you'd lose most of the Unicode set because those JREs default to legacy "ANSI" encodings. The proof is in the link I posted. `new InputStreamReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(myString, "UTF-16"), "UTF-16")` would be lossless.

Comment: hooray, using a 3rd party library to turn a one-liner into…a larger one-liner. Not to speak about useless conversion of a `String` into a `byte[]` array to convert the bytes back to `char`s then…

Comment: Actually taking a look at the implementation: `IOUtils.toInputStream(myString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` also just creates a ByteArrayInputStream: `new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(Charsets.toCharset(encoding)))`.

Answer (score 34):

Does it have to be specifically an InputStreamReader?  How about using [StringReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)?

Otherwise, you could use [StringBufferInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), but it's deprecated because of character conversion issues (which is why you should prefer StringReader).

Answer (score 17):

Same question as [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java#247169) - why not StringReader ?

If it has to be InputStreamReader, then:

```
String charset = ...; // your charset
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(charset);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais);
```

Comment: Nice, but 2nd line should be `byte[] bytes = charset.getBytes();`

Comment: I don't think so Abhishek. In my example, string is the instance of String that you wish to access using an InputStreamReader.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to get a) `Reader` functionality out of `InputStreamReader`, or b) `InputStream` functionality out of `InputStreamReader`?  You won't get b).  `InputStreamReader` is not an `InputStream`.

The purpose of `InputStreamReader` is to take an `InputStream` - a source of bytes - and decode the bytes to chars in the form of a `Reader`.  You already have your data as chars (your original String).  Encoding your String into bytes and decoding the bytes back to chars would be a redundant operation.

If you are trying to get a `Reader` out of your source, use `StringReader`.

If you are trying to get an `InputStream` (which only gives you bytes), use apache commons `IOUtils.toInputStream(..)` as suggested by other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
InputStream stream = new InputStreamOf(str);
```

Then, if you need a `Reader`:

```
Reader reader = new ReaderOf(stream);
```