# Render SVG stored in memory using JSR-226 (Blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry, svg

I have code that generates a data-driven SVG graph and I'd like to display the graph directly. 
The method:

```
javax.microedition.m2g.ScalableImage.createImage
```

can take either a URI or an InputStream as the source data for the graph, what would be a good way to pass my graph data in? It's in String form in memory, so from what I can see I can either create a custom class extending InputStream (would prefer not to), or write the SVG data to disk and have it read back in. Is there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will do you what you want:

[How do I turn a String into a InputStreamReader in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java)

I don't know if that will apply on BlackBerry though.