# parse an xml string in java?

Tags: java, xml

how do you  parse xml stored in a java string object?

Java's XMLReader only parses XML documents from a URI or inputstream. is it not possible to parse from a String containing an xml data?

Right now I have the following:

```
try {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = factory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 

    ContactListXmlHandler handler = new ContactListXmlHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(handler);
    xr.p
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And on my handler i have this:

```
public class ContactListXmlHandler extends DefaultHandler implements Resources {

    private List<ContactName> contactNameList = new ArrayList<ContactName>();

    private ContactName contactItem;

    private StringBuffer sb;

    public List<ContactName> getContactNameList() {
        return contactNameList;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startDocument();

        sb = new StringBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        if(localName.equals(XML_CONTACT_NAME)){
            contactItem = new ContactName();
        }

        sb.setLength(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            super.characters(ch, start, length);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sb.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.endDocument();
    }

    /**
     * where the real stuff happens
     */
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.endElement(arg0, arg1, arg2);

        if(contactItem != null){
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                contactItem.setUid(sb.toString());
                Log.d("handler", "setTitle = " + sb.toString());

            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                contactItem.setFullName(sb.toString());

            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                Log.d("handler", "adding rss item");
                contactNameList.add(contactItem);
            }

            sb.setLength(0);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [SAXParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) can [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource,%20org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler)) an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html).

An **InputSource** can take a **Reader** in its [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource(java.io.Reader))

So, you can put parse XML string via a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)

```
new InputSource(new StringReader("... your xml here....")));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com) (see this [blog post](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/24/java-xml-parsing-and-traversing.html)) with a one-liner:

```
XML xml = new XMLDocument("<document>...</document>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0573.html

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseXMLString {

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
     String xmlRecords =
      "<data>" +
      " <employee>" +
      "   <name>John</name>" +
      "   <title>Manager</title>" +
      " </employee>" +
      " <employee>" +
      "   <name>Sara</name>" +
      "   <title>Clerk</title>" +
      " </employee>" +
      "</data>";

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

        // iterate the employees
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
           Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

           NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
           Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
           System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

           NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
           line = (Element) title.item(0);
           System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
    output :
        Name: John
        Title: Manager
        Name: Sara
        Title: Clerk
    */    

  }

  public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
       CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
       return cd.getData();
    }
    return "?";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML might be simple enough to parse manually using the DOM or SAX API, but I'd still suggest using an XML serialization API such as [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html), or [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) instead because writing your own XML serialization/deserialization code is a drag.

Note that the XStream FAQ erroneously claims that you must use generated classes with JAXB:

> *How does XStream compare to JAXB (Java API for XML Binding)?*
>
> JAXB is a Java binding tool. It generates Java code from a schema and
>   you are able to transform from those classes into XML matching the
>   processed schema and back. Note, that you cannot use your own objects,
>   you have to use what is generated.

It seems this was true was true at one time, but JAXB 2.0 no longer requires you to use Java classes generated from a schema.

If you go this route, be sure to check out the side-by-side comparisons of the serialization/marshalling APIs I've mentioned:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html