# Convert a String to a xml Element java

Tags: java, xml

I want to convert a String to `org.jdom.Element`

```java
String s = "<rdf:Description rdf:about=\"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama\">";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Usually, I create a Document with root...

Answer (score 5):

There is more than one way to parse XML from string:

[Example 1](http://ideone.com/N4jIO):

```
  String xml = "Your XML";
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906936/395659):

Using a  SAXParser which can read an inputsource:

```
 SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
 DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
 saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("Your XML")), handler);
```

See: [SAXParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html), [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html)

Comment: No, it doesn't work, cause this intruction only set the name of the element.

Comment: @Abu why should this be a comment?

Comment: @pseudo2188 it returns an org.jdom.Element from the string whats the output you expect?

Comment: I think, the OP wants to parse a whole XML document which is contained in the string.

Comment: Not the whole document, 
in my input, I have a String, but this String corresponds to an XML element, I have to compare it with other variables witch are really XML elements, so I have to convert the first one

Comment: @pseudo2188 Sorry i missunderstood the question, i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Document` from your string. Look at JDOM FAQ: [How do I construct a Document from a String?](http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0210)
2. Use method [`Document.getRootElement()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Document.html#getRootElement%28%29) to access the root element.

(You mentioned package `org.jdom` so I assume you work with JDOM 1.1.)

Comment: I usually do this, but for my exemple it not necessary, cause, I have to declare namespaces that I used, and construct a valid XML

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use the Simple XML Framework from http://simple.sourceforge.net/.With this framework you can serialize and deserialize your objects easily. I hope this information can be important for you.