# How to download a xml file with content from inputtextarea?

Tags: java, xml, jsf, primefaces, download

I am trying to download a xml file using primefaces components. This part is working but I have on my page a inputtextarea, and I would like to have the text that I write in the inputtextarea written in the xml file that is downloaded. Could a developer help me ? Thank you.

my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <title>File Download</title>      
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/loading11.gif" />          
    </p:dialog>

    <p:inputTextarea id ="mytheinput"  value="#{fileDownloadView.mytext}" cols="115" autoResize="true" rows="20"  />  

    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
PF('statusDialog').show();
}

function stop() {
PF('statusDialog').hide();
}
</script>


</h:body>
</html>
```

My bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="fileDownloadView")
public class FileDownloadView {

private StreamedContent file;
private String mytext;

public FileDownloadView() {  
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream(mytext);
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "xml", "yourfile.xml");
}

public StreamedContent getFile() {
    return file;
}

public String getMytext() {
    return mytext;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few remarks**

1. Your `p:inputTextarea` should be inside the `h:form` element
2. Your bean's `mytext` property must have a **getter** (ok) AND a **setter** (missing!)
3. Your InputStream code comes from a PF example that returns the content of a resource picture file. You just want to create a stream from a string! Ask yourself [How do I turn a String into a Stream in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java)
4. The `InputStream` must be created on the fly because of the changing text (i.e. inside `getFile` instead of constructor)

**A little help**

```
public StreamedContent getFile() {
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream( mytext.getBytes() );
    StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "xml", "yourfile.xml");
    return file;
}

public String getMytext() {
    return mytext;
}

public void setMytext(String mytext) {
    this.mytext = mytext;
}
```