# Creating an input stream from a text file initialized programatically in Java

Tags: java, string, file, stream, arrays

I have a Class, that expects an InputStream on input.
Currently I am loading a text file from filesystem and creating FileInputStream, that is passed to this Class.

What I need is to eliminate the need of file in filesystem to be able to create an InputStream.

So I came up with solutions like:

- Storing a file into String variable and creating Stream out of it (escaping chars need to be done)
- Storing a file into byte array with hex values (no need to escape chars or care about content)

I am wondering if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: I dont get it... you want to read the content and remove the file from the filesystem?

Comment: Are you looking for ByteArrayInput/OutputStream? But this does not replace a File object if you want to read a real file from a file system.

Comment: Already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I studied your link and I do not believe the "answers" in there is sufficient to answer my question... I already said I know how to do it with String and ByteArray, they are talking only about these two solutions, I asked if there is another way...

Comment: If you have a file, and you need an `InputStream`, the `FileInputStream` class meets your need perfectly. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "What I need is to eliminate the need of file in filesystem to be able to create an InputStream." Simply because I want to hide this file to be not seen or edited.