# How to use OutputStream to write to a String

Tags: java, string, io, outputstream

I have a program in which I use a `PrintStream` object to write to a file. Is there a way to use something like a String Buffer or similar as the `OutputStream` for the object instead, so that I can use `print` to append to the String ?
I later want to be able to retrieve this String (obviously)

(ps. i wanna do this for testing purposes in my program)

Some info:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(myOutputStream);
...
ps.print(...);
...
ps.close();
```

I want to replace `myOutputStream` with some kind of String buffer which I can retrieve later and read.

As far as I know, in C++ we can do this as

```
stringstream ss;
ss << ...
```

How to do this in Java ?

Comment: ```StringBuilder``` or ```StringBuffer```?

Comment: You have to use you're `String` as a stream:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java