# Java File Transfer using JSch

Tags: java, jsch

I have a Java SFTP Transfer application working fine using a file that is saved on disk. I like to change the logic to use a string or stream. All the information I can find is that it only takes `FileInputStream`. Any help would be great.

```
ChannelSftp c = createSession();
try {
    File f = new File(workingFile);
    c.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Storing remote file failed. "+e.toString());
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the **JSch 0.1.44** (unofficial) Javadoc maintained by Paŭlo Ebermann found [here](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc), [`ChannelSftp`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) has several overloaded `put(...)` methods. So you can provide an `InputStream` (or any subclass), not just a `FileInputStream` reference. For example, `put(InputStream src, String dst)` would upload a file from an input stream `src` to the `dst`, which is *the remote destination file name, relative to the current remote directory*.

You can also provide the `String` path to the file you want transferred. For example, the `put(String src, String dst)` method with the parameters:

- `src` - *the local source file name, absolute or relative to the current local directory*.
- `dst` - *the remote destination file name, absolute or relative to the current remote directory*.

Comment: How will I convert an string to an InputStream object? I been testing with this code var is = new ByteArrayInputStream(connectorMessage.getRawData());

Comment: @THOMASJ.Mcdevitt: In Java you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java).