# compiling a jrxml string (NOT JRXML FILE) in JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an API which will create the report and we need to pass the JRXML content(whihc is passed as string from UI) for that,Now I want to compile the JRXML content before saving it into data base,One approach I have is that I can save the JRXML content into file system and then load that file and compile it,But I don't like it because if the compilation failed I need to delete that file from file system, So  wondering If I can compile the input JRXML content only before storing it into file.

I am passing the *JRXML* as a string to my method which should compile that *JRXML* string, but I don't want to store the content in file and then compile it

Comment: @PetterFriberg Please see my edit ,it is not the duplicate of the question which you refer.

Comment: @user3817378  `I am asking to compile the jasper string` - What do you mean? I don't know about the jasper strings and compilation of jasper string. Please explain

Comment: A jasper string = the content in a jasper file, if so then just create a inputstream from the string [how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java), then check the duplicate again.

Comment: @AlexK, The intention of putting the block letters was to avoid any confusion about what I was asking,I am no one to shout to anyone.

Comment: @AlexK It means that I want to compile the JRXML string or content of the JRXML file ,As I mention in my question ,I am passing the JRXML as a string to my method which should compile that JRXML string ,But I don't want to store the content in file and then compile.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That looks a solution ,I will try it. Thanks

Comment: If it works consider to accept the duplicate, since in the end it really is.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an input stream, not necessarily a file object for the `compile()` method like mentioned in the jasper docs.