# Java: How i pass the string in xml and get diffrent attribute

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an XML-String and, I want to get all `result`-elements with their `messageId`-,`designation`- and `status`-members from it. How can I do that?

```
"null
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <result>
        <status>-13</status>
        <messageid></messageid>
        <destination>null</destination>
    </result>
    <result>
        <status>-3</status>
        <messageid></messageid>
        <destination>911234567898</destination>
    </result>
    <result>
        <status>0</status>
        <messageid>146092209473920945</messageid>
        <destination>917827767338</destination>
    </result>
    <result>
        <status>0</status>
        <messageid>116092209473924510</messageid>
        <destination>918527593928</destination>
    </result>
    <result>
        <status>-3</status>
        <messageid></messageid>
        <destination>912345234567</destination>
    </result>
</results>"
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the `null` at the start really there? If so, you should work out why - that's not part of a valid XML document. Next, use an XML parser to parse the XML - there are *lots and lots* of XML tutorials around on the web. If you have problems, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get rid of the `null` part at the start of the `String`. A `InputStream` can be created from the rest of the `String` (see [How do I turn a String into a InputStreamReader in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java)). Parse that stream with a DOM parser and extract the `messageid`s with xpath:

```
String s = "null<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><results><result><status>-13</status><messageid></messageid><destination>null</destination></result><result><status>-3</status><messageid></messageid><destination>911234567898</destination></result><result><status>0</status><messageid>146092209473920945</messageid><destination>917827767338</destination></result><result><status>0</status><messageid>116092209473924510</messageid><destination>918527593928</destination></result><result><status>-3</status><messageid></messageid><destination>912345234567</destination></result></results>";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.substring(s.indexOf("<?xml")).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = builder.parse(is);
XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "//messageid";

NodeList list = (NodeList) path.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
List<String> messageIds = new ArrayList<>(list.getLength());
for (int i = 0, l = list.getLength(); i < l; i++) {
    messageIds.add(list.item(i).getTextContent());
}
System.out.println(messageIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));//your string xml data

Document doc = builder.parse(src);
String status= doc.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).getTextContent();
String messageid=doc.getElementsByTagName("messageid").item(0).getTextContent();
String designation=doc.getElementsByTagName("designation").item(0).getTextContent();
```