# Cannot get out the input from console after a new line character in BufferedReader

Tags: java

Following is the coding I currently have:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DictionarySearch{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = "";
    List<String> dicts = new ArrayList<>();

    line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null && !(line.trim().isEmpty())) {
      dicts.add(line);
      line = br.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Done adding");
    String partial = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Partial: " + partial);
  }
}
```

When I run my test, I place following values into console:

```
A
B
C
```

When I debug the code, `dicts` successfully contains String `A` and String `B`, but I cannot make `partial` equals to `C`. Is it means I using the wrong class to read the input from the console?

Comment: you could use a do-while to avoid your using of readline() in two different places that ultimately serve the same purpose

Comment: Is there a `newline` behind the `C`?

Comment: I will prefer to use java.util.Scanner instead of BufferedReader.

Comment: [Seems fine here](https://ideone.com/KDmRb2). I'd also suggest [using a String instead of reading from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-inputstreamreader-in-java) for the purposes of posting questions here, to allow for each reproducing and avoid any potential issues there.