# How do I apply the for-each loop to every character in a String?

Tags: java, string, loops, foreach, char

So I want to iterate for each character in a string.

So I thought:

```
for (char c : "xyz")
```

but I get a compiler error:

```
MyClass.java:20: foreach not applicable to expression type
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 443, accepted):

The easiest way to for-each every `char` in a `String` is to use `toCharArray()`:

```
for (char ch: "xyz".toCharArray()) {
}
```

This gives you the conciseness of for-each construct, but unfortunately `String` (which is immutable) must perform a defensive copy to generate the `char[]` (which is mutable), so there is some cost penalty.

From the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

> [`toCharArray()` returns] *a newly allocated character array* whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

There are more verbose ways of iterating over characters in an array (regular for loop, `CharacterIterator`, etc) but if you're willing to pay the cost `toCharArray()` for-each is the most concise.

Comment: Will the compiler recognize that a true copy is not needed and apply the appropriate optimizations?

Comment: @Pacerier No, the current Java compilers will never optimize code.

Comment: @RAnders00 So, in this case `toCharArray( )` is called 3 times?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet: Well, not entirely. In the comment he said something about the compiler which is the program that turns Java source code (`.java`) into bytecode (`.class`). Modern JVMs (this is what runs your bytecode [aka `.class` and `.jar` files]) *might* be able to optimize this, but I don't think they would do such aggressive optimizations, since that would mean method calls being omitted (which is generally not desirable in running code).

Comment: With a string length of `211900000`, time taken to complete `for (char c : str.toCharArray()) { }` is ~250ms and time taken to complete `for (char c : charArray) { }` is <10ms. Of course, these time values will depend on the hardware but the takeaway is that one method is significantly costly than the other.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet: No, the `toCharArray()` is not inside the loop body; it's only called once, and then the loop iterates over that resulting array.  (The for-each loop is different than the general `for`-loop, which evaluates the stop-condition each iteration.)

Comment: I think this is undesirable solution. The copy-overhead of toCharArray() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 66):

```
String s = "xyz";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
   char c = s.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: OP is expecting inhanced for loop.

Comment: Down voted because this is specifically not what OP asked for. While this is a valid solution it is entirely not what is being asked

Comment: No matter what the OP expected, this has better performance than for-each I guess.

Answer (score 13):

Another useful solution, you can work with this string as array of String

```
for (String s : "xyz".split("")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Elegant, but unfortunately it doesn't work if any elements of the string being `split()` map to more than one Java character, which is the case for almost all emoticons. For example, this variation of your example will loop four times rather than three: `for (String s : "xz".split("")) { System.out.println(s); }`

Answer (score 13):

If you use Java 8, you can use `chars()` on a `String` to get a `Stream` of characters, but you will need to cast the `int` back to a `char` as `chars()` returns an `IntStream`.

```
"xyz".chars().forEach(i -> System.out.print((char)i));
```

If you use Java 8 with [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use the `CharAdapter` class `forEach` method with a lambda or method reference to iterate over all of the characters in a `String`.

```
Strings.asChars("xyz").forEach(c -> System.out.print(c));
```

This particular example could also use a method reference.

```
Strings.asChars("xyz").forEach(System.out::print)
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the String object into an array of char using the [`toCharArray`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)() method of the String class:

```
String str = "xyz";
char arr[] = str.toCharArray(); // convert the String object to array of char

// iterate over the array using the for-each loop.       
for(char c: arr){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In **Java 8** we can solve it as:

```
String str = "xyz";
str.chars().forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.print((char)i));
```

The method chars() returns an `IntStream` as mentioned in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--):

> Returns a stream of int zero-extending the char values from this
>   sequence. Any char which maps to a surrogate code point is passed
>   through uninterpreted. If the sequence is mutated while the stream is
>   being read, the result is undefined.

### Why use `forEachOrdered` and not `forEach` ?

The behaviour of `forEach` is explicitly nondeterministic where as the `forEachOrdered` performs an action for each element of this stream, in the **encounter order of the stream** if the stream has a defined encounter order. So `forEach` does not guarantee that the order would be kept. Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797579/foreach-vs-foreachordered-in-java-8-stream) for more.

We could also use `codePoints()` to print, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47736566/1216775) for more details.

Comment: This creates multiple objects, so this answer isn't complete without the caveat that this may be less efficient than a simple indexed loop.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Java does not make `String` implement `Iterable<Character>`.  This could easily be done.  There is `StringCharacterIterator` but that doesn't even implement `Iterator`...  So make your own:

```
public class CharSequenceCharacterIterable implements Iterable<Character> {
    private CharSequence cs;

    public CharSequenceCharacterIterable(CharSequence cs) {
        this.cs = cs;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Character>() {
            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < cs.length();
            }

            @Override
            public Character next() {
                return cs.charAt(index++);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now you can (somewhat) easily run `for (char c : new CharSequenceCharacterIterable("xyz"))`...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a lambda in this case.

```
    String s = "xyz";
    IntStream.range(0, s.length()).forEach(i -> {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
    });
```

Answer (score -8):

For Travers an String you can also use `charAt()` with the string.

like :

```
String str = "xyz"; // given String
char st = str.charAt(0); // for example we take 0 index element 
System.out.println(st); // print the char at 0 index
```

`charAt()` is method of string handling in java which help to Travers the string for specific character.

Comment: do you know what `for (char st: "xyz".toCharArray()) {}` is?

Comment: -1 off-topic (topic: for-each), and use charAt instead of charAT