# Find substring between two strings

Tags: java, string

I have a string such as:
`file = "UserTemplate324.txt"`

I'd like to extract "324". How can I do this without any external libraries like Apache StringUtils?

Comment: Well are there going to be files with different names? Because if you only want the 324 of this file alone, that's easy

Comment: I would [for-each](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2451660/2891426) through the String, and if the current character is OK, I'd copy them into a Char Array. After the `for-each`, I'd build the new String from the Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude the non-digit characters:

```
String number = file.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

`\\D+` means a series of one or more non digit (0-9) characters and you replace any such series by `""` i.e. nothing, which leaves the digits only.

Comment: That'll do it. Thank you. Could you explain the first part?

Comment: This is a good simple solution (+1), and I would use it if it suits your file names, but just note that if the input is `"foo123bar456.txt"` the result will be `"123456"` (not `"456"`)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want "the digits just before the dot":

```
String number = str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)\\..*", "$1");
```

This uses regex to find and capture the digits and replace the entire input with them.

Of minor note is the use of a non-greedy quantifier to consume the minimum leading input (so as not to consume the leading part of the numbers too).

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, it says "Invalid escape sequence..."

Comment: @assylias is quite right. I've added the extra backslash.