# forEach vs forEachOrdered in Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I understand that these methods differ the order of execution but in all my test I cannot achieve different order execution.

Example:

```
System.out.println("forEach Demo");
Stream.of("AAA","BBB","CCC").forEach(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
System.out.println("forEachOrdered Demo");
Stream.of("AAA","BBB","CCC").forEachOrdered(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
```

Output:

```
forEach Demo
Output:AAA
Output:BBB
Output:CCC
forEachOrdered Demo
Output:AAA
Output:BBB
Output:CCC
```

Please provide examples when 2 methods will produce different outputs.

Comment: Try maybe with parallel streams.

Comment: @Pshemo is it only possible option?

Comment: Unspecified order does not imply “guaranteed to be different order”. It just means *unspecified*, which always implies the possibility to match the encounter order. There is no built-in shuffle function.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
Stream.of("AAA","BBB","CCC").parallel().forEach(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
Stream.of("AAA","BBB","CCC").parallel().forEachOrdered(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
```

The second line will always output

```
Output:AAA
Output:BBB
Output:CCC
```

whereas the first one is not guaranted since the order is not kept. `forEachOrdered` will processes the elements of the stream in the order specified by its source, regardless of whether the stream is sequential or parallel.

Quoting from [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) Javadoc:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For parallel stream pipelines, this operation does not guarantee to respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would sacrifice the benefit of parallelism.

When the [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) Javadoc states (emphasis mine):

> Performs an action for each element of this stream, **in the encounter order of the stream** if the stream has a defined encounter order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is it possible only for parallelStreams ?

Comment: Even if it only would apply to parallel streams right now - and I'm not saying it does - it still might break in the future if some intermediate steps get optimized to take advantage of unordered streams, e.g. a sort could use an unstable algorithm if the stream is unordered.

Comment: So it makes no sense to use `forEachOrdered` with `parallel` ?

Comment: @BhushanPatil Yes, that's correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336825/benefit-of-using-foreachordered-with-parallel-streams

Comment: Using forEachOrdered will process element by order then using parallel streams will loose benefits of parallelism. Please suggest.

Answer (score 38):

Although `forEach` shorter and looks prettier, I'd suggest to use `forEachOrdered` in every place where order matters to explicitly specify this. For sequential streams the `forEach` seems to respect the order and even stream API internal code [uses](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#270) `forEach` (for stream which is known to be sequential) where it's semantically necessary to use `forEachOrdered`! Nevertheless you may later decide to change your stream to parallel and your code will be broken. Also when you use `forEachOrdered` the reader of your code sees the message: "the order matters here". Thus it documents your code better.

Note also that for parallel streams the `forEach` not only executed in non-determenistic order, but you can also have it executed simultaneously in different threads for different elements (which is not possible with `forEachOrdered`).

Finally both `forEach`/`forEachOrdered` are rarely useful. In most of the cases you actually need to produce some result, not just side-effect, thus operations like `reduce` or `collect` should be more suitable. Expressing reducing-by-nature operation via `forEach` is usually considered as a bad style.

Comment: "Finally both forEach/forEachOrdered are rarely useful". I could not agree more. It seems these methods are over-used.

Comment: Why is it semantically necessary to use `forEachOrdered` in that code?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, it's user-specified stream (passed into `flatMap`). It can be ordered, so it must be placed into the resulting stream in the same order.

Comment: Why? Where in the contract of `flatMap` did you see that it says that it will be placed in the output in the same order?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, you are the real skeptic! `Stream.of("a", "b", "c").flatMap(s -> Stream.of("1", "2", "3").map(s::concat)).spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED)` returns true, thus the order for the resulting stream must be determined. If you feel that JDK documentation should explicitly say about this, feel free to submit a bug.

Comment: “forEach rarely useful”… As for filling a collection, I can see your point – but isn’t `list.addAll(stream.collect(toList))` taking twice the memory of `stream.forEach(list::add)` ? But what about `stream.forEach(this::doSomethingTotallyUnrelatedToFillingAList)` ?

Comment: I strongly disagree that `forEach` is rarely used. When you need to process large collections of data, you obviously will get the task done in parallel. It's quite useful to submit a lambda function there. And when I do need the results ordered, I use it with an IntStream; the processing method receives the input collection, the output will collection, along with the int from then stream, which is the *index* for both collections. This way, no thread safe data collection has to be used, which let's your code run faster, and due to the sync collections, order is still preserved.

Answer (score 22):

`forEach()` method performs an action for each element of this stream. For parallel stream, this operation does not guarantee to maintain order of the stream.

`forEachOrdered()` method performs an action for each element of this stream, guaranteeing that each element is processed in encounter order for streams that have a defined encounter order.

take the example below:

```
    String str = "sushil mittal";
    System.out.println("****forEach without using parallel****");
    str.chars().forEach(s -> System.out.print((char) s));
    System.out.println("\n****forEach with using parallel****");

    str.chars().parallel().forEach(s -> System.out.print((char) s));
    System.out.println("\n****forEachOrdered with using parallel****");

    str.chars().parallel().forEachOrdered(s -> System.out.print((char) s));
```

## Output:

```
****forEach without using parallel****

sushil mittal

****forEach with using parallel****

mihul issltat

****forEachOrdered with using parallel****

sushil mittal
```

Answer (score 0):

We may lose the benefits of parallelism if we use forEachOrdered() with parallel Streams.

As we know, In parallel programming element will print parallelly if we use forEach() method. so the order will not be fixed. But In the use of forEachOrdered() fixed order in parallel Streams.

Stream.of("AAA","BBB","CCC").forEachOrdered(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
Output:AAA
Output:BBB
Output:CCC