# How to sort TreeMap in descending order based on the value

Tags: java

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("apple", 5);
    map.put("orange", 8);
    map.put("pear", 3);
    map.put("watermelon", 10);
    map.put("melon", 1337);
```

How can I sort all the values in descending order and print them?

Answer (score 2):

`TreeMap` sorts the entries by keys, not be values, so you would have to do something like this:

```
map.values().stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It's a bit funny to print from a forEach, since it makes no guarantees about execution order in general. It would be  safer to use forEachOrdered.

Comment: @whaleberg hmmm? The stream is not parallel. `forEach` will execute in order.

Comment: It happens to execute in order, but there is no guarantee that the ordering won't change in different versions of Java or different compilers. That's why forEachOrdered exists. It is unlikely that oracle will change the sequential stream, so it's probably  safe, but I believe it would be better practice to go with the more explicitly ordered one. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: forEach vs forEachOrdered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797579/foreach-vs-foreachordered-in-java-8-stream

Comment: As that says,  "The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic" it happens to work now for  sequential streams, but that's an implementation detail subject to change.