# Pros and Cons of usage forEach and Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Starts from java 8 to iterate throug list I can use both:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
1. list.forEach(...)
2. list.stream().forEach(...)
```

Is it any advantages of using second case? To convert list to stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no advantages of using the second case, unless you have a parallel stream. There is a disadvantage, namely that `Stream.forEach()` doesn't guarantee to respect encounter order. A more accurate (but still unnecessary) equivalent would be `Stream.forEachOrdered()`.

Comment: Does the non-guarantee of encounter order of `forEach` also apply to non parallel streams that have ordered source?

Comment: @tsolakp Briefly, yes. See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34247318/1553851

Comment: Someone got to write better Javadoc:). Here is snippet from Javadoc as well. "If a stream is ordered, repeated execution of identical stream pipelines on an identical source will produce an identical result;"

Comment: @shmosel plus one, I just did not find the right words that even if forEach operates only via side-effects, adding elements to a list via `stream().forEach` is strongly discouraged and it might produce wrong results, while the other one would be ok.

Comment: @tsolakp Presumably that doesn't apply to operations involving side-effects, since they depend on unknown variables. But I agree that the language could be tightened up.

Comment: @Eugene OP never mentioned such a use. As for side-effects in general, I'll just quote the docs: *A small number of stream operations, such as `forEach()` and `peek()`, can operate only via side-effects; these should be used with care.*

Comment: @shmosel exactly, but that would count as a difference between them

Comment: I don't see why.

Answer (score 2):

No, in theory, the second option is worse than the first one - you pay the cost of instantiation/garbage-collection and calling a `Stream` instance and don't really get any benefit in return.

Additionally, in theory the iteration order of `Stream.forEach()` isn't deterministic.