# Benefit of using forEachOrdered with Parallel streams

Tags: java, java-8

The official Oracle documentation says:

> Note that you may lose the benefits of parallelism if you use
>   operations like forEachOrdered with parallel streams.
>   [Oracle - Parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)

Why would anyone use `forEachOrdered` with parallel stream if we are losing parallelism?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

depending on the *situation*, one does not lose *all* the benefits of parallelism by using `ForEachOrdered`.

Assume that we have something as such:

```
stringList.parallelStream().map(String::toUpperCase)
                           .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

In this case, we can guarantee that the `ForEachOrdered` terminal operation will print out the strings in uppercase in the encounter order *but* we should not assume that the elements will be passed to the `map` intermediate operation in the same order they were picked for processing. The `map` operation will be executed by multiple threads concurrently. So one may still benefit from parallelism but it's just that we’re not leveraging the full potential of parallelism. To conclude, we *should* use `ForEachOrdered` when it matters to perform an action in the encounter order of the stream.

**edit following your comment:**

> What happens when you skip `map` operation? I am more interested in
>   `forEachOrdered` right after `parallelStream()`

if you're referring to something as in:

```
 stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(action);
```

there is *no benefit* in doing such thing and I doubt that's what the designers had in mind when they decided to create the method. in such case, it would make more sense to do:

```
stringList.stream().forEach(action);
```

to extend on your question *"Why would anyone use forEachOrdered with parallel stream if we are losing parallelism"*, say you wanted to perform an action on each element with respect to the streams encounter order; in such case *you will need to use* `forEachOrdered` as the `forEach` terminal operation is *non deterministic* when used in parallel hence there is one version for *sequential* streams and one *specifically* for *parallel* streams.

Comment: What happens when you skip map operation? I am more interested in forEachOrdered right after `parallelStream()`

Comment: @Kaunteya not much changes, streams *are driven* by the terminal operation anyway

Comment: if you're referring to something like `stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(action);` and to answer your question _Why would anyone use forEachOrdered with parallel stream if we are losing parallelism_ , this is because you have no choice but to. say you want to perform an _action_ on each element with respect to the streams encounter order then you will need to use it as the `forEach` terminal operation is _non deterministic_ when used in parallel.

Comment: A more interesting example would be `stringList.parallelStream().sorted().forEachOrdered(action)`

Comment: @Holger... making this an interesting one would be the addition of the `sorted`? I can't tell what makes this one a *more* interesting one :|

Comment: @Eugene: for an ordered stream, the parallel workers have to wait at the consumer until all elements coming earlier in encounter order have been consumed, so the parallel processing of the `map` step (and all other immediately preceding stateless intermediate operations) is very limited. In contrast, a `sorted` step will perform the sorting of the entire stream in parallel without being affected by the constraints of the subsequent `forEachOrdered`. That would also apply to intermediate steps before the sorting, as those can also run concurrently without restrictions.

Comment: @Aominè Do you think `stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(action);` is not only provides any benefit over `stream().forEachOrdered(action)` but it also hogs on the threads in common fork-join threadpool for achieving the same thing ?

Comment: @Kaunteya it's possible to do `stream().forEachOrdered(action)` but ideally it's _much_ better to do `stream().forEach(action)` as the former is intended for parallel streams. i may be wrong but i doubt doing `stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(action);` will actually spin up multiple threads. the java doc states that `parallelStream()` _Returns a **possibly** parallel Stream with this collection as its source. It is allowable for this method to return a sequential stream._. So i am thinking `stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(action);` will only be executed in one thread.

Comment: Maybe, @Holger can enlighten us a little bit regarding your question as I am interested to know whether what I've said is valid or not.

Comment: @Aominè Look for the answer I have posted if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really get the question here. *Why?* because you simply have no alternative - you have so much data that parallel streams will help you (this still needs to be proven); but yet you still need to preserve the order - thus `forEachOrdered`. Notice that the documentation says **may** and not **will** lose that for sure - you would have to measure and see.

Answer (score 0):

I found stream().forEachOrdered() is ~50% faster than its parallel counterpart.  Plus the parallel one  uses at least one thread from common fork-join thread pool, which is - one less thread for other parallel streams running in JVM.

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        IntStream.range(0,10000000).parallel().forEachOrdered(i -> {
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            int p = 1 * 1 ;
        });
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }`