# How to find EOF in a string in java?

Tags: java, string, eof

I am working in school project. In that what they told is, I will be given a String which contains an actual program like....

> import java.io.*\npublic class A{\n...........EOF

And My job is to find particular regular expressions in that String(Program).

Now My question is..

```
void myFunc(String s)
{
 while(s.charAt(i) != EOF) /*needed replacement for EOF*/
 {
 // Actual Code
 }
}
```

In the above code, how to find whether EOF is reached in a string?

Comment: Will there actually going to be the characters "EOF"?

Comment: @DaveNewton I think yes. Because if not EOF , then how can they represent end of file/Program.

Comment: Bye not having any more string.

Comment: Haha. This is like trying to find Grid Squares, Bruce Light Batteries, or Frequency Grease. Good luck!

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but I think you can achieve what you want by operating on the string object directly rather than finding the EOF character.

Comment: Or use `"Hello World".toCharArray() `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no EOF character in a string. You just need to [iterate over the characters in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        
    //Process char
}
```

Comment: Ya. I too got confused in that only. Then How could I do that in this case?

Comment: Ha! I thinked a lot. But not this. well I try for this one.

Comment: there might be some eof character in there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: @Ray Tayek Why exactly would java worry about implementation details of the C standard library? The C standard doesn't even specify which value EOF has to have..

Comment: @Voo java would not. but you might have to read a file with a control z in it.

Comment: @RayTayek Terminal EOFs are an implementation detail, some terminals don't even have one and in either case Java luckily completely abstracts that concept away. If one reads a file with whatever representation ctrl-z has, it's just that sign and doesn't have any specific meaning (eg I can trivially create a file containing that character and that won't limit me in any way).

Answer (score 19):

It's unlikely that you need this - you probably just need to read till the end of the string, and since it's a representation of a file's contents, your teacher referred to it as EOF.

However...

There is a character called EOF.  It's also called control-Z, because that's how you type it.  If you want to include it in a string, you have to type it as "\u001a" as in:

```
String iHaveAnEof = "file ends here\u001a";
```

If you really need this, your teacher is probably older than me, and I'm probably old enough to be your grandfather ;-)

Comment: I don't know for which system you are talking about, but on GNU, it is Ctrl-D.

Comment: @AnonBird Most DEC systems, CP/M, MS-DOS and Windows used control-Z.  See "EOF", [ASCII Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: I wasn't doubting about your answer, sorry if it looked like it, but just an update to your answer for gnu users.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Input.txt"),"UTF-8"));

```
  char ch;
  int r;
  while(true)
  {
    r=rd.read();    //Reading a character in integer format
    if(r==-1)   //Checking for the End of File
      break;
    else
    {
      ch=(char)r;   //Converting to char format
  System.out.println(ch);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This actually stops at spaces, `=`, `;`, etc.  They all evaluate to `-1`.