# Fastest way to iterate over all the chars in a String

Tags: java, string, performance, char, iteration

In Java, what would the fastest way to iterate over all the chars in a String, this:

```
String str = "a really, really long string";
for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
}
```

Or this:

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, n = chars.length; i < n; i++) {
    char c = chars[i];
}
```

**EDIT :**

What I'd like to know is if the cost of repeatedly calling the `charAt` method during a long iteration ends up being either less than or greater than the cost of performing a single call to `toCharArray` at the beginning and then directly accessing the array during the iteration.

It'd be great if someone could provide a robust benchmark for different string lengths, having in mind JIT warm-up time, JVM start-up time, etc. and not just the difference between two calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: What happened to `for (char c : chars)`?

Comment: The first one should be faster, and anyway a string a char array, theoretically.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for the performance of using iterators, foreach. What I'd like to know is if the cost of repeatedly calling `charAt` ends up being either less than or greater than the cost of performing a single call to `toCharArray`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the second form in my question is equivalent to `for (char c : chars)`

Comment: Has anyone done analysis with [StringCharacterIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html)?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

FIRST UPDATE: Before you try this ever in a production environment (not advised), read this first: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue237.html
Starting from Java 9, the solution as described won't work anymore, because now Java will store strings as byte[] by default.

SECOND UPDATE: As of 2016-10-25, on my AMDx64 8core and source 1.8, there is no difference between using 'charAt' and field access. It appears that the jvm is sufficiently optimized to inline and streamline any 'string.charAt(n)' calls.

THIRD UPDATE: As of 2020-09-07, on my Ryzen 1950-X 16 core and source 1.14, 'charAt1' is 9 times slower than field access and 'charAt2' is 4 times slower than field access. Field access is back as the clear winner. Note than the program will need to use byte[] access for Java 9+ version jvms.

It all depends on the length of the `String` being inspected. If, as the question says, it is for **long** strings, the fastest way to inspect the string is to use reflection to access the backing `char[]` of the string.

A fully randomized benchmark with JDK 8 (win32 and win64) on an 64 AMD Phenom II 4 core 955 @ 3.2 GHZ (in both client mode and server mode) with 9 different techniques (see below!) shows that using `String.charAt(n)` is the fastest for small strings and that using `reflection` to access the String backing array is almost twice as fast for large strings.

## THE EXPERIMENT

- 9 different optimization techniques are tried.
- All string contents are randomized
- The test are done for string sizes in multiples of two starting with 0,1,2,4,8,16 etc.
- The tests are done 1,000 times per string size
- The tests are shuffled into random order each time. In other words, the tests are done in random order every time they are done, over 1000 times over.
- The entire test suite is done forwards, and backwards, to show the effect of JVM warmup on optimization and times.
- The entire suite is done twice, once in `-client` mode and the other in `-server` mode.

## CONCLUSIONS

### -client mode (32 bit)

For strings **1 to 256 characters in length**, calling `string.charAt(i)` wins with an average processing of 13.4 million to 588 million characters per second.

Also, it is overall 5.5% faster (client) and 13.9% (server) like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
```

than like this with a local final length variable:

```
    final int len = data.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
```

For long strings, **512 to 256K characters length**, using reflection to access the String's backing array is fastest. **This technique is almost twice as fast** as String.charAt(i) (178% faster). The average speed over this range was 1.111 billion characters per second.

The Field must be obtained ahead of time and then it can be re-used in the library on different strings. Interestingly, unlike the code above, with Field access, it is 9% faster to have a local final length variable than to use 'chars.length' in the loop check. Here is how Field access can be setup as fastest:

```
   final Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
   field.setAccessible(true);

   try {
       final char[] chars = (char[]) field.get(data);
       final int len = chars.length;
       for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           if (chars[i] <= ' ') {
               doThrow();
           }
       }
       return len;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
   }
```

### Special comments on -server mode

Field access starting winning after 32 character length strings in server mode on a 64 bit Java machine on my AMD 64 machine. That was not seen until 512 characters length in client mode.

Also worth noting I think, when I was running JDK 8 (32 bit build) in server mode, the overall performance was 7% slower for both large and small strings. This was with build 121 Dec 2013 of JDK 8 early release. So, for now, it seems that 32 bit server mode is slower than 32 bit client mode.

That being said ... it seems the only server mode that is worth invoking is on a 64 bit machine. Otherwise it actually hampers performance.

For 32 bit build running in `-server mode` on an AMD64, I can say this:

1. String.charAt(i) is the clear winner overall. Although between sizes 8 to 512 characters there were winners among 'new' 'reuse' and 'field'.
2. String.charAt(i) is 45% faster in client mode
3. Field access is twice as fast for large Strings in client mode.

Also worth saying, String.chars() (Stream and the parallel version) are a bust. Way slower than any other way. The `Streams` API is a rather slow way to perform general string operations.

### Wish List

Java String could have predicate accepting optimized methods such as contains(predicate), forEach(consumer), forEachWithIndex(consumer). Thus, without the need for the user to know the length or repeat calls to String methods, these could help parsing libraries `beep-beep beep` speedup.

Keep dreaming :)

Happy Strings!

~SH

### The test used the following 9 methods of testing the string for the presence of whitespace:

"charAt1" -- CHECK THE STRING CONTENTS THE USUAL WAY:

```
int charAtMethod1(final String data) {
    final int len = data.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

"charAt2" -- SAME AS ABOVE BUT USE String.length() INSTEAD OF MAKING A FINAL LOCAL int FOR THE LENGTh

```
int charAtMethod2(final String data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return data.length();
}
```

"stream" -- USE THE NEW JAVA-8 String's IntStream AND PASS IT A PREDICATE TO DO THE CHECKING

```
int streamMethod(final String data, final IntPredicate predicate) {
    if (data.chars().anyMatch(predicate)) {
        doThrow();
    }
    return data.length();
}
```

"streamPara" -- SAME AS ABOVE, BUT OH-LA-LA - GO PARALLEL!!!

```
// avoid this at all costs
int streamParallelMethod(final String data, IntPredicate predicate) {
    if (data.chars().parallel().anyMatch(predicate)) {
        doThrow();
    }
    return data.length();
}
```

"reuse" -- REFILL A REUSABLE char[] WITH THE STRINGS CONTENTS

```
int reuseBuffMethod(final char[] reusable, final String data) {
    final int len = data.length();
    data.getChars(0, len, reusable, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (reusable[i] <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

"new1" -- OBTAIN A NEW COPY OF THE char[] FROM THE STRING

```
int newMethod1(final String data) {
    final int len = data.length();
    final char[] copy = data.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (copy[i] <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

"new2" -- SAME AS ABOVE, BUT USE "FOR-EACH"

```
int newMethod2(final String data) {
    for (final char c : data.toCharArray()) {
        if (c <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return data.length();
}
```

"field1" -- FANCY!! OBTAIN FIELD FOR ACCESS TO THE STRING'S INTERNAL char[]

```
int fieldMethod1(final Field field, final String data) {
    try {
        final char[] chars = (char[]) field.get(data);
        final int len = chars.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (chars[i] <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

"field2" -- SAME AS ABOVE, BUT USE "FOR-EACH"

```
int fieldMethod2(final Field field, final String data) {
    final char[] chars;
    try {
        chars = (char[]) field.get(data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    for (final char c : chars) {
        if (c <= ' ') {
            doThrow();
        }
    }
    return chars.length;
}
```

## COMPOSITE RESULTS FOR CLIENT `-client` MODE (forwards and backwards tests combined)

Note: that the -client mode with Java 32 bit and -server mode with Java 64 bit are the same as below on my AMD64 machine.

```
Size     WINNER  charAt1 charAt2  stream streamPar   reuse    new1    new2  field1  field2
1        charAt    77.0     72.0   462.0     584.0   127.5    89.5    86.0   159.5   165.0
2        charAt    38.0     36.5   284.0   32712.5    57.5    48.3    50.3    89.0    91.5
4        charAt    19.5     18.5   458.6    3169.0    33.0    26.8    27.5    54.1    52.6
8        charAt     9.8      9.9   100.5    1370.9    17.3    14.4    15.0    26.9    26.4
16       charAt     6.1      6.5    73.4     857.0     8.4     8.2     8.3    13.6    13.5
32       charAt     3.9      3.7    54.8     428.9     5.0     4.9     4.7     7.0     7.2
64       charAt     2.7      2.6    48.2     232.9     3.0     3.2     3.3     3.9     4.0
128      charAt     2.1      1.9    43.7     138.8     2.1     2.6     2.6     2.4     2.6
256      charAt     1.9      1.6    42.4      90.6     1.7     2.1     2.1     1.7     1.8
512      field1     1.7      1.4    40.6      60.5     1.4     1.9     1.9     1.3     1.4
1,024    field1     1.6      1.4    40.0      45.6     1.2     1.9     2.1     1.0     1.2
2,048    field1     1.6      1.3    40.0      36.2     1.2     1.8     1.7     0.9     1.1
4,096    field1     1.6      1.3    39.7      32.6     1.2     1.8     1.7     0.9     1.0
8,192    field1     1.6      1.3    39.6      30.5     1.2     1.8     1.7     0.9     1.0
16,384   field1     1.6      1.3    39.8      28.4     1.2     1.8     1.7     0.8     1.0
32,768   field1     1.6      1.3    40.0      26.7     1.3     1.8     1.7     0.8     1.0
65,536   field1     1.6      1.3    39.8      26.3     1.3     1.8     1.7     0.8     1.0
131,072  field1     1.6      1.3    40.1      25.4     1.4     1.9     1.8     0.8     1.0
262,144  field1     1.6      1.3    39.6      25.2     1.5     1.9     1.9     0.8     1.0
```

## COMPOSITE RESULTS FOR SERVER `-server` MODE (forwards and backwards tests combined)

Note: this is the test for Java 32 bit running in server mode on an AMD64. The server mode for Java 64 bit was the same as Java 32 bit in client mode except that Field access starting winning after 32 characters size.

```
Size     WINNER  charAt1 charAt2  stream streamPar   reuse    new1    new2  field1  field2
1        charAt     74.5    95.5   524.5     783.0    90.5   102.5    90.5   135.0   151.5
2        charAt     48.5    53.0   305.0   30851.3    59.3    57.5    52.0    88.5    91.8
4        charAt     28.8    32.1   132.8    2465.1    37.6    33.9    32.3    49.0    47.0
8          new2     18.0    18.6    63.4    1541.3    18.5    17.9    17.6    25.4    25.8
16         new2     14.0    14.7   129.4    1034.7    12.5    16.2    12.0    16.0    16.6
32         new2      7.8     9.1    19.3     431.5     8.1     7.0     6.7     7.9     8.7
64        reuse      6.1     7.5    11.7     204.7     3.5     3.9     4.3     4.2     4.1
128       reuse      6.8     6.8     9.0     101.0     2.6     3.0     3.0     2.6     2.7
256      field2      6.2     6.5     6.9      57.2     2.4     2.7     2.9     2.3     2.3
512       reuse      4.3     4.9     5.8      28.2     2.0     2.6     2.6     2.1     2.1
1,024    charAt      2.0     1.8     5.3      17.6     2.1     2.5     3.5     2.0     2.0
2,048    charAt      1.9     1.7     5.2      11.9     2.2     3.0     2.6     2.0     2.0
4,096    charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       8.7     2.1     2.6     2.6     1.9     1.9
8,192    charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       7.6     2.2     2.5     2.6     1.9     1.9
16,384   charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       6.9     2.2     2.5     2.5     1.9     1.9
32,768   charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       6.1     2.2     2.5     2.5     1.9     1.9
65,536   charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       5.5     2.2     2.4     2.4     1.9     1.9
131,072  charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       5.4     2.3     2.5     2.5     1.9     1.9
262,144  charAt      1.9     1.7     5.1       5.1     2.3     2.5     2.5     1.9     1.9
```

## FULL RUNNABLE PROGRAM CODE

(to test on Java 7 and earlier, remove the two streams tests)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

/**
 * @author Saint Hill <http://stackoverflow.com/users/1584255/saint-hill>
 */
public final class TestStrings {

    // we will not test strings longer than 512KM
    final int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 1024 * 256;

    // for each string size, we will do all the tests
    // this many times
    final int TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestStrings().run();
    }

    void run() throws Exception {

        // double the length of the data until it reaches MAX chars long
        // 0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 ... 
        final List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int n = 0; n <= MAX_STRING_SIZE; n = (n == 0 ? 1 : n * 2)) {
            sizes.add(n);
        }

        // CREATE RANDOM (FOR SHUFFLING ORDER OF TESTS)
        final Random random = new Random();

        System.out.println("Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.");
        System.out.printf("==== FORWARDS (tries per size: %s) ==== \n", TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE);

        printHeadings(TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);

        for (int size : sizes) {
            reportResults(size, test(size, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random));
        }

        // reverse order or string sizes
        Collections.reverse(sizes);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.");
        System.out.printf("==== BACKWARDS (tries per size: %s) ==== \n", TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE);

        printHeadings(TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);

        for (int size : sizes) {
            reportResults(size, test(size, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random));

        }
    }

    ///
    ///
    ///  METHODS OF CHECKING THE CONTENTS
    ///  OF A STRING. ALWAYS CHECKING FOR
    ///  WHITESPACE (CHAR <=' ')
    ///  
    ///
    // CHECK THE STRING CONTENTS
    int charAtMethod1(final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // SAME AS ABOVE BUT USE String.length()
    // instead of making a new final local int 
    int charAtMethod2(final String data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // USE new Java-8 String's IntStream
    // pass it a PREDICATE to do the checking
    int streamMethod(final String data, final IntPredicate predicate) {
        if (data.chars().anyMatch(predicate)) {
            doThrow();
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // OH LA LA - GO PARALLEL!!!
    int streamParallelMethod(final String data, IntPredicate predicate) {
        if (data.chars().parallel().anyMatch(predicate)) {
            doThrow();
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // Re-fill a resuable char[] with the contents
    // of the String's char[]
    int reuseBuffMethod(final char[] reusable, final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        data.getChars(0, len, reusable, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (reusable[i] <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // Obtain a new copy of char[] from String
    int newMethod1(final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        final char[] copy = data.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (copy[i] <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // Obtain a new copy of char[] from String
    // but use FOR-EACH
    int newMethod2(final String data) {
        for (final char c : data.toCharArray()) {
            if (c <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // FANCY!
    // OBTAIN FIELD FOR ACCESS TO THE STRING'S
    // INTERNAL CHAR[]
    int fieldMethod1(final Field field, final String data) {
        try {
            final char[] chars = (char[]) field.get(data);
            final int len = chars.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (chars[i] <= ' ') {
                    doThrow();
                }
            }
            return len;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    // same as above but use FOR-EACH
    int fieldMethod2(final Field field, final String data) {
        final char[] chars;
        try {
            chars = (char[]) field.get(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        for (final char c : chars) {
            if (c <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return chars.length;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Make a list of tests. We will shuffle a copy of this list repeatedly
     * while we repeat this test.
     *
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    List<Jobber> makeTests(String data) throws Exception {
        // make a list of tests
        final List<Jobber> tests = new ArrayList<Jobber>();

        tests.add(new Jobber("charAt1") {
            int check() {
                return charAtMethod1(data);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("charAt2") {
            int check() {
                return charAtMethod2(data);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("stream") {
            final IntPredicate predicate = new IntPredicate() {
                public boolean test(int value) {
                    return value <= ' ';
                }
            };

            int check() {
                return streamMethod(data, predicate);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("streamPar") {
            final IntPredicate predicate = new IntPredicate() {
                public boolean test(int value) {
                    return value <= ' ';
                }
            };

            int check() {
                return streamParallelMethod(data, predicate);
            }
        });

        // Reusable char[] method
        tests.add(new Jobber("reuse") {
            final char[] cbuff = new char[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

            int check() {
                return reuseBuffMethod(cbuff, data);
            }
        });

        // New char[] from String
        tests.add(new Jobber("new1") {
            int check() {
                return newMethod1(data);
            }
        });

        // New char[] from String
        tests.add(new Jobber("new2") {
            int check() {
                return newMethod2(data);
            }
        });

        // Use reflection for field access
        tests.add(new Jobber("field1") {
            final Field field;

            {
                field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }

            int check() {
                return fieldMethod1(field, data);
            }
        });

        // Use reflection for field access
        tests.add(new Jobber("field2") {
            final Field field;

            {
                field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }

            int check() {
                return fieldMethod2(field, data);
            }
        });

        return tests;
    }

    /**
     * We use this class to keep track of test results
     */
    abstract class Jobber {

        final String name;
        long nanos;
        long chars;
        long runs;

        Jobber(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        abstract int check();

        final double nanosPerChar() {
            double charsPerRun = chars / runs;
            long nanosPerRun = nanos / runs;
            return charsPerRun == 0 ? nanosPerRun : nanosPerRun / charsPerRun;
        }

        final void run() {
            runs++;
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            chars += check();
            nanos += System.nanoTime() - time;
        }
    }

    // MAKE A TEST STRING OF RANDOM CHARACTERS A-Z
    private String makeTestString(int testSize, char start, char end) {
        Random r = new Random();
        char[] data = new char[testSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (char) (start + r.nextInt(end));
        }
        return new String(data);
    }

    // WE DO THIS IF WE FIND AN ILLEGAL CHARACTER IN THE STRING
    public void doThrow() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bzzzt -- Illegal Character!!");
    }

    /**
     * 1. get random string of correct length 2. get tests (List<Jobber>) 3.
     * perform tests repeatedly, shuffling each time
     */
    List<Jobber> test(int size, int tries, Random random) throws Exception {
        String data = makeTestString(size, 'A', 'Z');
        List<Jobber> tests = makeTests(data);
        List<Jobber> copy = new ArrayList<>(tests);
        while (tries-- > 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(copy, random);
            for (Jobber ti : copy) {
                ti.run();
            }
        }
        // check to make sure all char counts the same
        long runs = tests.get(0).runs;
        long count = tests.get(0).chars;
        for (Jobber ti : tests) {
            if (ti.runs != runs && ti.chars != count) {
                throw new Exception("Char counts should match if all correct algorithms");
            }
        }
        return tests;
    }

    private void printHeadings(final int TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, final Random random) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("  Size");
        for (Jobber ti : test(0, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random)) {
            System.out.printf("%9s", ti.name);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private void reportResults(int size, List<Jobber> tests) {
        System.out.printf("%6d", size);
        for (Jobber ti : tests) {
            System.out.printf("%,9.2f", ti.nanosPerChar());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is interesting that apparently a "performance expert" @ Sun (2008) disagrees - and stated that `.charAt()` should inline, which apparently isn't happening:  http://markmail.org/message/uc2c4cs5f4qntzhe

Comment: Ha ha. A lot of things *should* happen to optimize code at the compiler end. But they often do not happen.  My results still stand!

Comment: @SaintHill you can flag your question for moderator attention and ask them nicely to remove the wiki status from your answer, to get all the rep points that you are due here. :)

Comment: While detailed, this whole test does not take into account the garbage collection aspect of the algorithms, which /should/ be bumping the result in charAt's favour compared to the allocating strategies.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the suggestion. I will do as you say since this is my 'one hit wonder' here on this forum :)

Comment: @krosenvold First -- CASE 1 (charAt) is already favoured compared to the allocating strategy CASE 3. CASE 2 uses a reusable buffer.

Comment: @krosenvold Second -- GC should not factor since -> for the last test (experiment 2), for each string made, the full range of test cases is performed. And it is always performed in a fully random order. As such, the actual times spent garbage collecting are evenly distributed among all the tests and not any one test is subject to the GC fee. Therefor, for each new string, randomly apply test a,b,c,d OR b,d,c,a OR ... Everything is randomized. Also proved, creating new char[] is actually very efficient at the higher iteration counts - in spite of the overhead of creating new objects.

Comment: @krosenvold Lastly -- You do raise a good point about GC. I did not post the code for experiment #2 and it does not carry out the tests in the same way as experiment #1. Trust me that (1) a test random string is generated (2) the 4 tests are done on the string (3) the 4 tests are done in random order and (4) the time spent is just the time doing the work for each test case. The full code is too bulky to post here. But you get the idea.

Comment: Was this test run in server JVM or client JVM? The best optimizations are only done in server JVM. If you ran using the default 32 bit JVM and no arguments, then you ran in client mode.

Comment: @ceklock Honestly, it was a while ago now and I did it on my development machine.

Comment: Did we consider the fact that char[] chars = str.toCharArray(); itself takes O(n) time?

Comment: Getting the backing buffer is problematic in the case of substrings, or strings created using String(char[], int, int), as you get the entire buffer (at least on Android), but your indexing will be zero based.  However, if you know that you don't have a substring, it will work fine.

Comment: @prewett You bring up a valid issue because in a real-life scenario of working with other's API, there is no guarantee it is not a substring.

Comment: What about the performance of [StringCharacterIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html)?

Comment: Any idea why "for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)" is faster than defining data.length() as a final local variable?

Comment: Defining a variable, at all, requires a stack operation in the method byte code. But the optimizations, from recognizing your algorithm, could fast track that repeat operation in the actual machine code, without the overhead of  variable alocation.   Such optimizations sometimes exist in the bytecode compilers, sometimes not. It all depends on whether the jvm is smart enough :-)

Comment: The server compiler takes longer to start optimizing the code (e.g. CompileThreshold 10000 instead of 1500 on the client compiler), so if you are running this without an appropriate warm up period it won't be able to perform the optimizations. In order to make sure you are actually testing the iterations, you have to use the values, otherwise a smart and aggressive compiler may just completely ignore that code. Also don't use Random on micro benchmarks.

Comment: Forgive my slowness, but what do the numbers in your results actually represent? Size I see is array size, you documented that, but what are the numbers in the table? Why are the numbers higher for short array sizes? I would have guessed this meant the long arrays were being processed faster than short ones, but of course that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, I'm disappointed that Stream and the parallel version are a bust. Can we still take advantage of "conventional", old-school Java concurrency to improve speed? We must, right? but my expectations are often defied.

Comment: @DavidS the numbers are the rate (in nanoseconds) per character inspected. Smaller is better.

Comment: @SaintHill be warned that starting from Java 9, the solution as described won't work anymore, because now Java will store strings as `byte[]` by default; check this [article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue237.html).

Comment: Thanks. That's why I added the update at the top on the answer.

Comment: @DavidS: the implementation of `String.char()` is indeed poor, especially the parallel performance. This has been [recognized and fixed in Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071477). In Java 8, you might notice `CharBuffer.wrap(string).chars()` performing better than `string.chars()`, especially with parallel processing.

Comment: @SaintHill Defining a variable requires *what* stack operation in the method bytecode? What is the bytecode instruction? This is all BS. The stack frame is allocated on method entry, and whether it is one slot or a hundred the cost is the same. This is all BS.

Comment: @EJP I posted this in 2012, using the current Java version at the time, and tested on an 8 core AMD PC. The code is all above along with real results - don't let the door hit you on the way out ;-)

Answer (score 15):

This is just micro-optimisation that you shouldn't worry about.

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
```

returns you a copy of `str` character arrays (in JDK, it returns a copy of characters by calling `System.arrayCopy`).

Other than that, `str.charAt()` only checks if the index is indeed in bounds and returns a character within the array index.

The first one doesn't create additional memory in JVM.

Comment: Does not answer the question. This question is about performance. For all you know, the OP may have discovered that iterating over strings is a major cost in their application.

Answer (score 10):

*Just for curiosity and to compare with Saint Hill's answer.*

If you need to process heavy data you should not use JVM in client mode. Client mode is not made for optimizations.

Let's compare results of @Saint Hill benchmarks using a JVM in Client mode and Server mode.

```
Core2Quad Q6600 G0 @ 2.4GHz
JavaSE 1.7.0_40
```

See also: [Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

---

**CLIENT MODE:**

```
len =      2:    111k charAt(i),  105k cbuff[i],   62k new[i],   17k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      4:    285k charAt(i),  166k cbuff[i],  114k new[i],   43k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      6:    315k charAt(i),  230k cbuff[i],  162k new[i],   69k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      8:    333k charAt(i),  275k cbuff[i],  181k new[i],   85k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     12:    342k charAt(i),  342k cbuff[i],  222k new[i],  117k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     16:    363k charAt(i),  347k cbuff[i],  275k new[i],  152k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     20:    363k charAt(i),  392k cbuff[i],  289k new[i],  180k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     24:    375k charAt(i),  428k cbuff[i],  311k new[i],  205k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     28:    378k charAt(i),  474k cbuff[i],  341k new[i],  233k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     32:    376k charAt(i),  492k cbuff[i],  340k new[i],  251k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     64:    374k charAt(i),  551k cbuff[i],  374k new[i],  367k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    128:    385k charAt(i),  624k cbuff[i],  415k new[i],  509k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    256:    390k charAt(i),  675k cbuff[i],  436k new[i],  619k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    512:    394k charAt(i),  703k cbuff[i],  439k new[i],  695k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   1024:    395k charAt(i),  718k cbuff[i],  462k new[i],  742k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   2048:    396k charAt(i),  725k cbuff[i],  471k new[i],  767k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   4096:    396k charAt(i),  727k cbuff[i],  459k new[i],  780k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   8192:    397k charAt(i),  712k cbuff[i],  446k new[i],  772k field access.   (chars/ms)
```

---

**SERVER MODE:**

```
len =      2:     86k charAt(i),   41k cbuff[i],   46k new[i],   80k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      4:    571k charAt(i),  250k cbuff[i],   97k new[i],  222k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      6:    666k charAt(i),  333k cbuff[i],  125k new[i],  315k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =      8:    800k charAt(i),  400k cbuff[i],  181k new[i],  380k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     12:    800k charAt(i),  521k cbuff[i],  260k new[i],  545k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     16:    800k charAt(i),  592k cbuff[i],  296k new[i],  640k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     20:    800k charAt(i),  666k cbuff[i],  408k new[i],  800k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     24:    800k charAt(i),  705k cbuff[i],  452k new[i],  800k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     28:    777k charAt(i),  736k cbuff[i],  368k new[i],  933k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     32:    800k charAt(i),  780k cbuff[i],  571k new[i],  969k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =     64:    800k charAt(i),  901k cbuff[i],  800k new[i],  1306k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    128:    1084k charAt(i),  888k cbuff[i],  633k new[i],  1620k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    256:    1122k charAt(i),  966k cbuff[i],  729k new[i],  1790k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =    512:    1163k charAt(i),  1007k cbuff[i],  676k new[i],  1910k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   1024:    1179k charAt(i),  1027k cbuff[i],  698k new[i],  1954k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   2048:    1184k charAt(i),  1043k cbuff[i],  732k new[i],  2007k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   4096:    1188k charAt(i),  1049k cbuff[i],  742k new[i],  2031k field access.   (chars/ms) 
len =   8192:    1157k charAt(i),  1032k cbuff[i],  723k new[i],  2048k field access.   (chars/ms)
```

---

**CONCLUSION:**

As you can see, server mode is much faster.

Comment: Thanks for posting. So, for large strings, field access is still 2x faster than charAt(). In fact, field access became even faster overall with it leading after 28 length strings (crazy!!)  So ... server mode makes everything faster. Very interesting!

Comment: Yeah, the reflective method is really faster. Interesting.

Comment: btw: newer JVMs automatically figures out which of -server or -client that works best (usually): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html

Comment: @jontejj in practice it is not so simple. If you are running a 32-bit JVM on Windows, then the JVM will always default to client.

Answer (score 7):

The first one using `str.charAt` should be faster.

If you dig inside the source code of `String` class, we can see that `charAt` is implemented as follows:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index + offset];
}
```

Here, all it does is index an array and return the value.

Now, if we see the implementation of `toCharArray`, we will find the below:

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count];
    getChars(0, count, result, 0);
    return result;
}

public void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char dst[], int dstBegin) {
    if (srcBegin < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcBegin);
    }
    if (srcEnd > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd);
    }
    if (srcBegin > srcEnd) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd - srcBegin);
    }
    System.arraycopy(value, offset + srcBegin, dst, dstBegin,
         srcEnd - srcBegin);
}
```

As you see, it is doing a `System.arraycopy` which is definitely going to be a tad slower than not doing it.

Comment: It's silly that the String#charAt should do an extra index check, when the index is checked anyway on array access.

Comment: At the risk of reviving an 8 year old thread... The char array behind a string might be bigger than the string itself. That is, if you had a string "abcde" and then you used substring to extract "bcd" into a new string, the new string will be backed by the exact same char array as the first string. That's why the string class maintains an offset and a count - so it knows which chars in the array are the ones that represent this string. So the range check is important otherwise it would be possible to access characters beyond the ends of this string.

Answer (score 4):

`String.toCharArray()` creates new char array, means allocation of memory of string length, then copies original char array of string using `System.arraycopy()` and then returns this copy to caller.
 String.charAt() returns character at position `i` from original copy, that's why `String.charAt()` will be faster than `String.toCharArray()`.
Although, `String.toCharArray()` returns copy and not char from original String array, where `String.charAt()` returns character from original char array.
Code below returns value at the specified index of this string.

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

code below returns a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite @Saint Hill's answer if you consider the time complexity of **str.toCharArray()**,

the first one is faster even for very large strings. You can run the code below to see it for yourself.

```
        char [] ch = new char[1_000_000_00];
    String str = new String(ch); // to create a large string

    // ---> from here
    long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
    }
    // ---> to here
    System.out.println("str.charAt(i):"+(System.nanoTime()-currentTime)/1000000.0 +" (ms)");

    /**
     *   ch = str.toCharArray() itself takes lots of time   
     */
    // ---> from here
    currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    ch = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = ch[i];
    }
    // ---> to  here
    System.out.println("ch = str.toCharArray() + c = ch[i] :"+(System.nanoTime()-currentTime)/1000000.0 +" (ms)");
```

output:

```
str.charAt(i):5.492102 (ms)
ch = str.toCharArray() + c = ch[i] :79.400064 (ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like niether is faster or slower

```
    public static void main(String arguments[]) {


        //Build a long string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            sb.append("a really, really long string");
        }
        String str = sb.toString();
        for (int testscount = 0; testscount < 10; testscount ++) {


            //Test 1
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int c = 0; c < 10000000; c++) {
                for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
                    char chr = str.charAt(i);
                    doSomethingWithChar(chr);//To trick JIT optimistaion
                }
            }

            System.out.println("1: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

            //Test 2
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
            for(int c = 0; c < 10000000; c++) {
                for (int i = 0, n = chars.length; i < n; i++) {
                    char chr = chars[i];
                    doSomethingWithChar(chr);//To trick JIT optimistaion
                }
            }
            System.out.println("2: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            System.out.println();
        }


    }


    public static void doSomethingWithChar(char chr) {
        int newInt = chr << 2;
    }
```

For long strings I'll chose the first one. Why copy around long strings?
Documentations says:

> public char[] toCharArray()
>   Converts this string to a new character array.
>
> Returns:
>   a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

**//Edit 1**

I've changed the test to trick JIT optimisation.

**//Edit 2**

Repeat test 10 times to let JVM warm up.

**//Edit 3**

Conclusions:

First of all `str.toCharArray();` copies entire string in memory. It can be memory consuming for long strings. Method `String.charAt( )` looks up char in char array inside String class checking index before.
It looks like for short enough Strings first method (i.e. `chatAt` method) is a bit slower due to this index check. But if the String is long enough, copying whole char array gets slower, and the first method is faster. The longer the string is, the slower `toCharArray` performs. Try to change limit in `for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)` loop to see it.
If we let JVM warm up code runs faster, but proportions are the same.

After all it's just micro-optimisation.

Comment: Could you try the `for:in` option, just for the fun of it?

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed: it doesn't let the JIT make its optimizations; the JIT could remove the loops completely, since they don't do anything.

Comment: String is not na `Iterable` nor array.

Comment: Consider using `System.nanoTime()` for more accurate timings

Comment: This is not a valid test, you've 'warmed' up your JVM with Test 1, which can skew the results towards Test 2's favor. The OP's whole question smells of micro optimization anyway.

Comment: True. After warming up (see Edit 2) both times are smaller bu still close to each other. In my example second test is a bit faster. But if I make the String longer, the first one is faster. The longer string, the slower second test is, due to char array copy. Just do it the first way.

Comment: @PeterGwiazda please edit your answer and add that last comment as the conclussion, and I'll accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

The second one causes a new char array to be created, and all chars from the String to be copied to this new char array, so I would guess that the first one is faster (and less memory-hungry).

Answer (score 1):

In many real-world scenarios, both the character value and the index into the original string are necessary. Here's another suite of `String` iteration benchmarks, tested using openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18 and JMH 1.35.

### Source Code

```java
/**
 * Iterates over a string, much like {@link CharacterIterator}, but faster.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Caution:</strong> This class offers minimal bounds checking to eke
 * out some efficiency.
 * </p>
 */
public final class FastCharacterIterator {

  private final String mS;
  private final int mLen;

  /**
   * Starts at 0, not guaranteed to be within bounds.
   */
  private int mPos;

  /**
   * Constructs a new iterator that can advance through the given string
   * one character at a time.
   *
   * @param s The string to iterate.
   */
  public FastCharacterIterator( final String s ) {
    assert s != null;

    mS = s;
    mLen = s.length();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the iterated index. The return value is not guaranteed to be
   * within the string bounds.
   *
   * @return The iterated index.
   */
  public int index() {
    return mPos;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the character at the currently iterated position in the string.
   * This method performs bounds checking by catching an exception because
   * usually parsing is complete when there are no more characters to iterate,
   * meaning that 99.99% of the time, explicit bounds checking is superfluous.
   *
   * @return {@link CharacterIterator#DONE} if there are no more characters.
   */
  public char current() {
    try {
      return mS.charAt( mPos );
    } catch( final Exception ex ) {
      return DONE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the next character in the string and consumes it.
   *
   * @return {@link CharacterIterator#DONE} if there are no more characters.
   */
  public char advance() {
    try {
      return mS.charAt( ++mPos );
    } catch( final Exception ex ) {
      return DONE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the next character in the string without consuming it. Multiple
   * consecutive calls to this method will return the same value.
   *
   * @return {@link CharacterIterator#DONE} if there are no more characters.
   */
  public char peek() {
    try {
      return mS.charAt( mPos + 1 );
    } catch( final Exception ex ) {
      return DONE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Advances to the next character in the string, without bounds checking.
   */
  public void next() {
    mPos++;
  }

  /**
   * Advances to the previous character in the string, without bounds checking.
   */
  public void prev() {
    mPos--;
  }

  /**
   * Answers whether {@link #next()} followed by {@link #current()} is safe.
   *
   * @return {@code true} if there are more characters to be iterated.
   */
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return mPos < mLen;
  }

  /**
   * Parse all characters that match a given function.
   *
   * @param f The function that determines when skipping stops.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings( "StatementWithEmptyBody" )
  public void skip( final Function<Character, Boolean> f ) {
    assert f != null;

    while( f.apply( advance() ) ) ;

    // The loop always overshoots by one character.
    prev();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a string from a subset of consecutive characters in the string
   * being iterated. The calling class is responsible for bounds-checking.
   *
   * @param began The starting index, must be greater than or equal to zero
   *              and less than or equal to {@code ended}.
   * @param ended The ending index, must be less than the string length.
   * @return A substring of the iterated string.
   * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException Either or both parameters exceed the
   *                                   string's boundaries.
   */
  public String substring( final int began, final int ended ) {
    assert began >= 0;
    assert began <= ended;
    assert ended < mLen;

    return mS.substring( began, ended );
  }
}
```

### Testing Code

The full source code used for testing:

```java
import com.whitemagicsoftware.keenquotes.util.FastCharacterIterator;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static java.lang.Math.random;
import static java.text.CharacterIterator.DONE;

/**
 * Higher scores mean faster code:
 *
 * <pre>
 * Benchmark                     Mode   Cnt    Score    Error  Units
 * test_CharArrayIterator        thrpt   25  753.960 ±  0.972  ops/s
 * test_CharAtIterator           thrpt   25  878.016 ±  0.884  ops/s
 * test_FastCharacterIterator    thrpt   25  803.041 ± 48.422  ops/s
 * test_StreamIterator           thrpt   25  101.416 ±  0.053  ops/s
 * test_StringCharacterIterator  thrpt   25  580.341 ±  0.432  ops/s
 * test_StringTokenizer          thrpt   25  174.121 ±  8.282  ops/s
 * </pre>
 */
@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
public class StringIterationBenchmark {
  private static final int STRLEN = 1024 * 1024;
  private static final String CHARSET =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklm nopqrstuvxyz 01234 5 6789";

  private static final String sText;

  static {
    final var len = CHARSET.length();
    final var buffer = new StringBuilder( STRLEN );

    for( var i = 0; i < STRLEN; i++ ) {
      buffer.append( CHARSET.charAt( (int) (len * random()) ) );
    }

    sText = buffer.toString();
  }

  private static String getText() {
    return sText;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_FastCharacterIterator() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var i = new FastCharacterIterator( s );
    var spaces = 0;

    char ch = ' ';

    while( (ch = i.advance()) != DONE ) {
      if( ch == ' ' ) {
        spaces++;
      }
    }

    fail( i.index(), s.length() );
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_CharAtIterator() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var length = s.length();
    var index = 0;
    var spaces = 0;

    while( index < length ) {
      final var ch = s.charAt( index );

      if( ch == ' ' ) {
        spaces++;
      }

      index++;
    }

    fail( index, length );
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_StringCharacterIterator() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var i = new StringCharacterIterator( s );
    var index = 0;
    var spaces = 0;

    char ch = ' ';

    while( ch != DONE ) {
      ch = i.next();

      if( ch == ' ' ) {
        spaces++;
      }

      index++;
    }

    fail( index, s.length() );
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_CharArrayIterator() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var i = s.toCharArray();
    var index = 0;
    var spaces = 0;

    for( final var ch : i ) {
      if( ch == ' ' ) {
        spaces++;
      }

      index++;
    }

    fail( index, s.length() );
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_StringTokenizer() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var i = new StringTokenizer( s, " ", true );
    var index = 0;
    var spaces = 0;

    while( i.hasMoreTokens() ) {
      final var token = i.nextToken();

      if( token.isBlank() ) {
        spaces++;
      }

      index += token.length();
    }

    fail( index, s.length() );
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void test_StreamIterator() {
    final var s = getText();
    final var index = new AtomicInteger();
    final var spaces = new AtomicInteger();

    s.chars().forEach( codepoint -> {
      final var ch = Character.valueOf( (char) codepoint );

      if( ch == ' ' ) {
        spaces.incrementAndGet();
      }

      index.incrementAndGet();
    } );

    fail( index.get(), s.length() );
  }

  private static void fail( final int index, final int length ) {
    if( index != length ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( "Fail" );
    }
  }
}
```

### Comments

Feel free to improve the code and re-run the benchmarks. Gripes will be sent to `/dev/null`. StackOverflow is a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an update for [The Coordinator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876086/1366594) since there is no way this would fit in a comment.

I updated to code to use the `byte[]` backing and ran it with one of the newer JVMs and it appears that they handle loops like this much better. Here are my results on a Java 21 Jvm in client:

```
Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.
==== ALL RESULTS (tries per size: 10000) ==== 
  Size   Winner  charAt1  charAt2   streamstreamPar    reuse     new1     new2   field1   field2
     0  charAt1    46.00    46.00    66.00    96.00    49.00    48.00    49.00    50.00    53.00
     1  charAt1    44.00    44.00    66.00    94.00    49.00    48.00    48.00    51.00    51.00
     2  charAt1    23.50    23.50    38.00   874.50    28.00    27.50    27.00    28.00    28.50
     4  charAt1    12.75    14.25    20.75   800.75    14.50    15.25    15.25    16.00    15.50
     8  charAt1     6.75     7.00    11.88   519.75     9.38     8.13     9.38     8.50     8.75
    16  charAt2     4.31     4.13     7.69   363.06     5.38     6.06     5.25     5.94     4.88
    32  charAt2     2.47     2.28     5.13   184.59     3.03     3.09     3.41     3.22     3.44
    64  charAt2     1.50     1.39     3.30   113.84     1.83     1.83     3.64     1.69     1.73
   128  charAt2     0.95     0.88     2.62    55.47     1.30     1.16     1.40     1.17     1.04
   256  charAt2     0.66     0.65     2.24    29.65     1.05     0.79     1.02     0.90     0.74
   512  charAt2     0.52     0.47     1.96    19.77     0.87     0.63     0.88     0.74     0.55
  1024  charAt2     0.44     0.38     1.82     9.93     0.72     0.50     0.83     0.65     0.46
  2048  charAt2     0.42     0.35     1.78     6.09     0.68     0.53     0.76     0.64     0.42
  4096  charAt2     0.39     0.35     1.75     4.07     0.70     0.50     0.76     0.61     0.40
  8192  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.71     2.36     0.67     0.49     0.76     0.58     0.38
 16384  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.71     1.63     0.68     0.50     0.76     0.58     0.37
 32768  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.71     1.28     0.66     0.51     0.77     0.58     0.37
 65536  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.71     1.20     0.67     0.49     0.77     0.57     0.37
131072  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.72     1.15     0.69     0.51     0.78     0.58     0.37
262144  charAt2     0.37     0.31     1.72     0.92     0.73     0.52     0.79     0.58     0.37
```

Here is the modified code I used to run it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
/**
 * Taken and modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876086/1366594
 * @author Saint Hill <http://stackoverflow.com/users/1584255/saint-hill>
 */
public final class TestStrings {

    // we will not test strings longer than 512KM
    final int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 1024 * 256;

    // for each string size, we will do all the tests
    // this many times
    final int TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestStrings().run();
    }

    void run() throws Exception {

        // double the length of the data until it reaches MAX chars long
        // 0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 ...
        final List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int n = 0; n <= MAX_STRING_SIZE; n = (n == 0 ? 1 : n * 2)) {
            sizes.add(n);
        }

        // CREATE RANDOM (FOR SHUFFLING ORDER OF TESTS)
        final Random random = new Random();

        System.out.println("Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.");
        System.out.printf("==== FORWARDS (tries per size: %s) ==== \n", TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE);

        printHeadings(TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);
        HashMap<Integer, List<Jobber>> allResults = new HashMap<>(sizes.size());
        for (Integer size : sizes) {
            allResults.put(size, new ArrayList<>(10));
        }
        //warm-up
        for (int size : sizes.subList(0, sizes.size() / 2)) {
            test(size, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);
        }

        for (int size : sizes) {
            var results = test(size, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);
            reportResults(size, results);
            allResults.get(size).addAll(results);
        }

        // reverse order or string sizes
        Collections.reverse(sizes);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.");
        System.out.printf("==== BACKWARDS (tries per size: %s) ==== \n", TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE);

        printHeadings(TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);

        for (int size : sizes) {
            var results = test(size, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);
            reportResults(size, results);
            allResults.get(size).addAll(results);
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Rate in nanoseconds per character inspected.");
        System.out.printf("==== ALL RESULTS (tries per size: %s) ==== \n", TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE);


        Collections.reverse(sizes);
        printHeadings(TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random);
        for (int size : sizes) {
            var jobs = allResults.get(size);
            var byName = jobs.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(item->item.name, item->item, (left, right)->
                            new Jobber(left.name) {
                                {
                                    nanos = (left.nanos + right.nanos) / 2;
                                    chars = left.chars;
                                    runs = left.runs;
                                }
                                @Override
                                int check() {
                                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                                }
                            }));
            var jobNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>(jobs.stream().
                    map(item->item.name).toList());
            var results = new ArrayList<Jobber>(jobNames.size());
            for (String name : jobNames) {
                results.add(byName.get(name));
            }
            reportResults(size, results);
        }
    }

    ///
    ///
    ///  METHODS OF CHECKING THE CONTENTS
    ///  OF A STRING. ALWAYS CHECKING FOR
    ///  WHITESPACE (CHAR <=' ')
    ///
    ///
    // CHECK THE STRING CONTENTS
    int charAtMethod1(final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // SAME AS ABOVE BUT USE String.length()
    // instead of making a new final local int
    int charAtMethod2(final String data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            if (data.charAt(i) <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // USE new Java-8 String's IntStream
    // pass it a PREDICATE to do the checking
    int streamMethod(final String data, final IntPredicate predicate) {
        if (data.chars().anyMatch(predicate)) {
            doThrow();
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // OH LA LA - GO PARALLEL!!!
    int streamParallelMethod(final String data, IntPredicate predicate) {
        if (data.chars().parallel().anyMatch(predicate)) {
            doThrow();
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // Re-fill a resuable char[] with the contents
    // of the String's char[]
    int reuseBuffMethod(final char[] reusable, final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        data.getChars(0, len, reusable, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (reusable[i] <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // Obtain a new copy of char[] from String
    int newMethod1(final String data) {
        final int len = data.length();
        final char[] copy = data.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (copy[i] <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return len;
    }

    // Obtain a new copy of char[] from String
    // but use FOR-EACH
    int newMethod2(final String data) {
        for (final char c : data.toCharArray()) {
            if (c <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return data.length();
    }

    // FANCY!
    // OBTAIN FIELD FOR ACCESS TO THE STRING'S
    // INTERNAL CHAR[]
    int fieldMethod1(final Field field, final String data) {
        try {
            final byte[] chars = (byte[]) field.get(data);
            final int len = chars.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if ((((char)chars[i]) & 0xff) <= ' ') {
                    doThrow();
                }
            }
            return len;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    // same as above but use FOR-EACH
    int fieldMethod2(final Field field, final String data) {
        final byte[] chars;
        try {
            chars = (byte[]) field.get(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        for (final byte c : chars) {
            if ((((char)c) & 0xff) <= ' ') {
                doThrow();
            }
        }
        return chars.length;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Make a list of tests. We will shuffle a copy of this list repeatedly
     * while we repeat this test.
     *
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    List<Jobber> makeTests(String data) throws Exception {
        // make a list of tests
        final List<Jobber> tests = new ArrayList<Jobber>();

        tests.add(new Jobber("charAt1") {
            int check() {
                return charAtMethod1(data);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("charAt2") {
            int check() {
                return charAtMethod2(data);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("stream") {
            final IntPredicate predicate = new IntPredicate() {
                public boolean test(int value) {
                    return value <= ' ';
                }
            };

            int check() {
                return streamMethod(data, predicate);
            }
        });

        tests.add(new Jobber("streamPar") {
            final IntPredicate predicate = new IntPredicate() {
                public boolean test(int value) {
                    return value <= ' ';
                }
            };

            int check() {
                return streamParallelMethod(data, predicate);
            }
        });

        // Reusable char[] method
        tests.add(new Jobber("reuse") {
            final char[] cbuff = new char[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

            int check() {
                return reuseBuffMethod(cbuff, data);
            }
        });

        // New char[] from String
        tests.add(new Jobber("new1") {
            int check() {
                return newMethod1(data);
            }
        });

        // New char[] from String
        tests.add(new Jobber("new2") {
            int check() {
                return newMethod2(data);
            }
        });

        // Use reflection for field access
        tests.add(new Jobber("field1") {
            final Field field;

            {
                field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }

            int check() {
                return fieldMethod1(field, data);
            }
        });

        // Use reflection for field access
        tests.add(new Jobber("field2") {
            final Field field;

            {
                field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }

            int check() {
                return fieldMethod2(field, data);
            }
        });

        return tests;
    }

    /**
     * We use this class to keep track of test results
     */
    abstract class Jobber {

        final String name;
        long nanos;
        long chars;
        long runs;

        Jobber(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        abstract int check();

        final double nanosPerChar() {
            double charsPerRun = chars / runs;
            long nanosPerRun = nanos / runs;
            return charsPerRun == 0 ? nanosPerRun : nanosPerRun / charsPerRun;
        }

        final void run() {
            runs++;
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            chars += check();
            nanos += System.nanoTime() - time;
        }
    }

    // MAKE A TEST STRING OF RANDOM CHARACTERS A-Z
    private String makeTestString(int testSize, char start, char end) {
        Random r = new Random();
        char[] data = new char[testSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (char) (start + r.nextInt(end));
        }
        return new String(data);
    }

    // WE DO THIS IF WE FIND AN ILLEGAL CHARACTER IN THE STRING
    public void doThrow() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bzzzt -- Illegal Character!!");
    }

    /**
     * 1. get random string of correct length 2. get tests (List<Jobber>) 3.
     * perform tests repeatedly, shuffling each time
     */
    List<Jobber> test(int size, int tries, Random random) throws Exception {
        String data = makeTestString(size, 'A', 'Z');
        List<Jobber> tests = makeTests(data);
        List<Jobber> copy = new ArrayList<>(tests);
        while (tries-- > 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(copy, random);
            for (Jobber ti : copy) {
                ti.run();
            }
        }
        // check to make sure all char counts the same
        long runs = tests.get(0).runs;
        long count = tests.get(0).chars;
        for (Jobber ti : tests) {
            if (ti.runs != runs && ti.chars != count) {
                throw new Exception("Char counts should match if all correct algorithms");
            }
        }
        return tests;
    }

    private void printHeadings(final int TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, final Random random) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("  Size   Winner");
        for (Jobber ti : test(0, TRIES_PER_STRING_SIZE, random)) {
            System.out.printf("%9s", ti.name);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private void reportResults(int size, List<Jobber> tests) {
        System.out.printf("%6d", size);
        String winner = "";
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Jobber ti : tests) {
            if (ti.nanosPerChar() < min){
                winner = ti.name;
                min = ti.nanosPerChar();
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%9s", winner);
        for (Jobber ti : tests) {
            System.out.printf("%,9.2f", ti.nanosPerChar());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

So, it looks like your standard `for` loop is the fastest option now

Edit: Also, with the newer JVMs, you will need to launch java with this option or you will not be getting the backing array for string: `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`