# Reading one character at a time from a large string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a big string having at most 100000 character. Instead of using `string.charAt[index]` to read a character from the string, I converted that string into char array using `string.toCharArray()` method and now i am working with `charArray[index]`. which takes less time than `string.charAt[index]` method. However i want to know that, is there any other way which is faster than `string.toCharArray();` method?

Comment: How did you determine that that `string.charAt(index)` is slower?  I wouldn't think it would be slower.

Comment: For your convenience, maybe I can suggest using [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)

Comment: I noticed the `System.getTimeinMills()` and `string.charAt(index)` also uses the array indexing. so better to have an array.

Comment: @Ravi Joshi: *"using string.charAt[index] to read a character from the string"*... String's *charAt* does *not* read a character from the String. It reads a Java *char*, which is totally inadequate to hold all the Unicode characters. A character, since Java 1.4, may need more than one Java *char* to be represented using *char*.  A website like Stackoverflow, for example, fully supports Unicode and all the Unicode codepoints.  Java's *char* primitive does not.

Comment: @TacticalCoder: Thank you for this information. i did not aware of this fact. However in my case the string is composed of only lower case alphabets i.e. a-z.

Comment: @TacticalCoder : what you say is wrong. A char primitive IS a unicode character. Maybe you are confusing with the byte primitive ? From the official doc : "The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character." source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html Example : char rr = '華';

Comment: @Pierre Henry: no, I am not confusing anything ; ) Many Unicode codepoints need two Java char to be encoded. By using the .charAt(...) method on such a Unicode codepoint you'd be reading only part of that codepoint. That is why in this day and age methods like *charAt* and *length* are mostly broken. You want to use *codePointAt* instead.  Example: how do you put the character 'U+1040B' inside a Java *char*?  You simply can't do it.  See answer from 100K+ SO user here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280801   (*"...a Java char holds a UTF-16 code unit instead of a Unicode character..."*)

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. I was persuaded that unicode used only 16 bits max. Thanks for pointing this out. I am not looking forward to have to work with those "astral" planes ;)

Comment: This problem already discussed in stack 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a faster way. But please correct me!

A String instance is backed by a char array. charAt() does some index checks which may be the cause for it being slower than working with the array returned by toCharArray(). toCharArray() simply does a System.arraycopy() of the backing array.

Comment: while using `string.charAt[index]`, Is every time an `char[string.length()]` is created? If yes, then it may be the reason of its less performance.