# isLetter Method isn't working in Java

Tags: java

Every time I write `Character.isLetter(4))`
it highlights `isLetter`...

Please help. I am trying to make a program that you have to tell the age to continue, but if you enter letters, an error pops up.

this is my full code, and it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Prmtrs1
{
public static int user_age2;
public static String user_age;
public static void main(String args[]) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Prmtrs2 POblect = new Prmtrs2 ();

System.out.println("Type in your name in here! ");
String name = input.nextLine();

POblect.Hello(name);
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Enter your age,  " + name);
user_age = input.nextLine();
while(user_age.matches("\\d+")) {
    System.out.println("enter numbers from 0 to 9");
    user_age = input.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Your age is  " + user_age + ", "  + name);
int user_age2 = Integer.parseInt(user_age);
if(user_age2 >= 18)
{
    System.out.println("So...");
System.out.println("You are eligible to Vote, " + name + "!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("So...");
System.out.println("You are not eligible to vote, " + name + "!");
}
}
}
```

Comment: *I am trying to make a program that you have to tell the age to continue* Then your code makes even less sense... show more of it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question?

Comment: 1) *"this is my full code"* That code does not compile due to a reference to `Prmtrs2`. 2) But even if it did, entering an update as an answer is not the correct way to do things. Instead [edit] the question to include new code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to write `Character.isLetter('4')`, `'4'` is a `char`, while `4` is an `int`.

`Character.isLetter` expects a `char` or an `int` codePoint.

You should also consider using regex and doing `s.matches("\\d+")` (where `s` is your input string) to see if your string consists solely of digits. The `matches` function takes in a regular expression.

In the example I just showed you `\d` means "digit" and `+` means "one or more".

But if you want to use `Character.isLetter` this can be done like so:

```
for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Character.isLetter(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-) is probably better than using `char`. In general, we shouldn't be operating on `char` directly unless we know something about the source data. Something like `s.codePoints().noneMatch(Character::isLetter)`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280911/2891664.