# counting the number of zeros

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that gets a .txt file that only has something like 10000010000010000010001

I'm trying to count the number of zeros and output it like  5 5 5 3. I thought if I convert a string into a `double` or `int` I could write an `if` or `for` loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.io.File test2 = new java.io.File("test3.txt");

        try
        {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            String num = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(num);

            double n = Double.parseDouble(num);
            System.out.println(n);
        } 
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }   

       }

}
```

Comment: Where do you attempt to count the zeroes...?

Comment: Please mention where is the problem?

Comment: For one, it's not recommended to drop questions and leave. Since there will be people asking for clarification. Questions tend to get deleted if they are unanswerable - which is the case if the OP disappears and does not stay to answer comments.

Comment: If you aren't going to bother to put in any effort, why should we bother to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
char[] numArray = num.toCharArray();
  int counter=0;
  for(int i=0;i<numArray.length;i++) {
     if(numArray[i]=='0') {
        counter++; 
     }
     if((i==numArray.length-1&&counter>0)||(counter>0&&numArray[i]!='0')) {
        System.out.println("Number of Zeroes: "+counter);
        counter=0;
     }
  }
```

Some important points:

1) It's best to use an array of `char` values here, instead of operating using a `double`, because a `char` array can store many more values- the example you posted is too long for a `double` to handle.

2) Most of this should be self-explanatory (at least, if you study it bit-by-bit), but in case the `i==numArray.length-1` part is confusing, this ensures that if the string ends with a 0, the final count of 0's will be printed out as well.

This should work for any string you can throw at it- including values besides 0 and 1, if you need support for it!

Comment: So, if line doesn't end with a 0 it will print `Number of Zeroes: 0` at the end.

Comment: @defaultlocale, almost- if the line ends with more than one non-zero value, it will print `Number of Zeroes: 0` at the end- ending with a single non-zero value would still function fine, which is why I missed the error. You are quite right that my code was flawed though- edited, and thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, why do you people hate `String.charAt` so much?

Comment: @defaultlocale (Not sure if I have to keep tagging you, but oh well), that's a fair question- there's a great evaluation of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string
... in this solution, it was merely a force of habit- using a `char` array is (possibly) as fast as `charAt` for this type of operation. But the array option has more potential later on for other operations, such as swapping values or repeatably checking them, so it's often more useful.

Answer (score 2):

where is your effort?
you can simply try (if your string contains only 1s and 0s):

```
    String[] splitArr = num.split("1");
    String countStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {
        if( ! splitArr[i].isEmpty() )
            countStr += splitArr[i].length();
    }
    System.out.println(countStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ZeroCounter {

ArrayList <Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
DataInputStream inStream;

long inFileSize;
long outFileSize;

// Track how many bytes we've read. Useful for large files.
int byteCount;

    public ZeroCounter() {
    }

//read the file and turn it into an array of integers
public void readFile(String fileName) {

    try {
        // Create a new File object, get size
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        inFileSize = inputFile.length();

        // The constructor of DataInputStream requires an InputStream
        inStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    }

    // Oops.  Errors.
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Read the input file
    try {

        // While there are more bytes available to read...
        while (inStream.available() > 0) {

            // Read in a single byte and store it in a character
            int c = (int)inStream.readByte();

            if ((++byteCount)% 1024 == 0)
                System.out.println("Read " + byteCount/1024 + " of " + inFileSize/1024 + " KB...");

            // Print the integer to see them for debugging purposes
            //System.out.print(c);
            // Add the integer to an ArrayList
            fileArray.add(c);
        }

        // clean up
        inStream.close();
        System.out.println("File has been converted into an ArrayList of Integers!");
    }

    // Oops.  Errors.
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Print the ArrayList contents for debugging purposes
    //System.out.println(fileArray);
}


public void countZeroes() {
    int zeroCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if (listOfNumbers.get(i) == 0) {
            zeroCounter++;
        }
        else if (listOfNumbers.get(i) != 0 && zeroCounter > 0) {
            //this only prints the number of zeroes if the zero counter isn't zero
            System.out.println(zeroCounter + " ");
            zeroCounter = 0;
        }

        else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZeroCounter comp = new ZeroCounter();
        comp.readFile("test3.txt");
        comp.countZeroes();
    }
}
```