# how to find length after decimal point of a double number without removing trailing zeroes in java?

Tags: java

Suppose you have a double number say `Double d = 12.123223800000`.
How can we find length of number from decimal point till the end including all trailing zeroes in it.

```
Double d = 12.123223800000;
String t = d.toString();
```

Here it's removing all the trailing zeroes from double number.

Comment: Take the length and then add infinity zeros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting the number of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853921/counting-the-number-of-zeros)

Comment: @yassadi How is that a duplicate?

Comment: What is the difference between 12.123223800000 and 12.1232238?

Comment: The trailing zeros removed while you initialize it to variable

Comment: `Double d = 12.123223800000;` will just store `12.1232238`, so you've already lost the zeros.

Comment: A floating point value doesn't have a number of trailing or leading zeros. It just has a value which is the closest representation to the one you have. i.e. it's not even exactly `12.1232238`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to assign the string directly? Java primitives don't keep trailing zeros because of their binary representation, yet in Mathematics trailing zeros are meaningless .. and so on.
This sample would *kinda* work

```
Double d = 12.123223800000;
String str = "12.123223800000"; // d.toString() won't work here
int length = str.length() - str.indexOf(".");
System.out.println(String.format("%."+ length +"f", d)); 
//prints out - 12.1232238000000
```

Comment: I am using Double.toString(d) here.

Comment: @AayushiTayal Then I guess... there is no option to do so, unless you specify as a hard-coded constant how many digits after the decimal point you want.

Comment: if we'll take double value as a String input (String str = "12.123223800000"), then there are other options also, but don't know how we can convert double value to string without removing zeroes.

Comment: 1. str = str.substring(str.indexOf(".")+1);
     int len = str.length()+1; .........2. There is another option also,we can parse the string to double value.. it'll give the number in exponential form.String str = "12.123223800000"; 
    int length = str.length() - str.indexOf(".");Double d2 =Double.parseDouble(str.substring(str.indexOf('.')+1));String ch = d2.toString();int o = ch.indexOf('E'); String v=ch.substring(o+1); (The value of v will give you length after decimal point-1)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between `12.123223800000` and `12.1232238`. The trailing zeros are removed while you initialize it to Double. If you still need such solution

```
String d = "12.123223800000";
System.out.println((d.length()-d.indexOf("."))-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(d))
int decimalPlaces = text.length()  - text.indexOf('.') - 1;
```

There is no way to get the trailing zeros counted because they don't affect the mathematical value of your double figure.
Edit: Except you assign your value directly to a string. With Javas primitve types, it is not possible