# First letter of String to Char

Tags: java, string

What I have is a student with a name and firstletter

So I have  a class student like:

```
private String name = "Unknown";

private char nameLetter = "u"; 

public void identify()
{
    System.out.println("Student first letter : " + nameLetter);
    System.out.println("Student name : " + name);

}

public void setName(String newName)
{
    name = newName;
    nameLetter = newName.substring(0);
}
```

But i get the error cant convert from string to char.

I know I could make a String nameLetter instead of char but I want to try it with char.

Comment: Use single quotes when use `char`, like: `char nameLetter = 'u';`

Comment: This is where your IDE would tell you which methods of String return a `char` (assuming you don't want to read the Javadoc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"u"` is a string literal, `'u'` a char.

Specifally, you need to replace `nameLetter = newName.substring(0);` with `nameLetter = newName.charAt(0);` as the former returns a `string`, the latter a `char`.

Answer (score 7):

You need this:

```
nameLetter = newName.charAt(0);
```

Of course you must check that `newName`'s length is at least 1, otherwise there would be an exception:

```
public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
    if (newName != null && newName.length() > 0) {
        nameLetter = newName.substring(0);
    } else {
        nameLetter = '-'; // Use some default.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use newName != null isn't it impossible to call the method without a parameter?  (just asking not trying to be smart)

Comment: @SvenB One cannot call it without a parameter, but it is perfectly possible to pass `null` instead of a `String` (not good, but possible). Like this: `myObj.setName(null);` Without a `null` check the method would throw an exception.

Comment: Would except you answer if it mentioned  "u" is a string literal, 'u' a char. thx anyway the other answer didnt post the filter you had. so  i upvoted it anyway but else you were the answer

Comment: @SvenB "accept you answer if it mentioned "u" is a string literal, 'u' a char" I thought the compiler has already told you that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose character primitives with `'` instead of `"`

```
private char nameLetter = 'u';
```

Use `charAt` instead of `substring` for extracting characters from `Strings`

```
nameLetter = newName.charAt(0);
```

Read: [Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
nameLetter = newName.toCharArray[0];
```

or you can try

```
nameLetter = newName.charAt[0];
```

To know the difference between both this approaches, you can see the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
nameLetter = newName.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `String#charAt(int)` function.