# Java mutable "String" with efficient per-char operations: toCharArray() or getBytes()?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character, mutable

I want to do some efficient per-character replacements in a java String, which is the better approach, to work with `.toCharArray()` or `.getBytes()` ?

Example code:

```
// big loop {
    String s = "..###.##...#";
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    c[4] = '$';
    c[8] = 'A';
    // etc
// }
```

If there are some differences between these 2 approaches, or if one is advisable over the other, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Have a look at similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string (Fastest way to iterate over all the chars in a String)

Comment: @BrianRoach am looking for efficiency (array-based operations), not a builder

Comment: @NeerajKrishna am looking to *modify* the string, not just iterate, so that question is not the same.

Comment: @vikingsteve Ignoring that it's unlikely you need such "efficiency" ... a `StringBuilder` is a wrapper around a `char[]` and does exactly what you're describing as wanting to do, providing the methods to do so. It has a constructor you pass your existing `String` to.

Comment: @BrianRoach ok, I see, but there's still no good reason to use a wrapper when I can use an array.

Comment: +1 for `StringBuilder`: go for the more convenient API over low-level access.

Comment: Why do i need an api full of operations i dont need? There is nothing wrong with [] as it suits the use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toCharArray` is better. That way you don't have to deal with encoding. At least not in the normal case (except for characters outside of the Unicode BMP, which are encoded as two surrogate chars). Basically, if you don't have to deal with Chinese text, that's not a problem.

The conversion from a `String` to a `char` array is faster than `toBytes()`: it's basically an array copy, without character encoding trouble. Internally, a `String` contains a `char[]`, and (at least for Java 7 and newer), not much else.

It's also faster to construct a `String` back from a `char` array than from a `byte` array, because no character encoding is needed.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that was exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder`, which is like a mutable string:

```
String s = "..###.##...#";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.setCharAt(4, '$');
```

There are lots of other methods you can use to change the contents. When you're done:

```
s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: s/StringBuffer/StringBuilder/ ... unless you really need thread safety

Comment: I'm looking for efficieny, so an array would suit me better than a buffer. I should add that my Strings are fixed length.

Comment: You making assumptions about the "efficiency" of a class without knowing how it actually works. Want to make a guess as to what's *inside* a StringBuilder?

Comment: @JonSkeet I swear I was thinking StringBuilder... of course it should be that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare character values, use `toCharArray()`.

If you want to compare the binary values of the UTF-8 encoding of the
characters, use `getBytes()`.

`toCharArray` is generally faster than `toByteArray`, but often slower than `charAt`.