# Removing a character from a string efficiently

Tags: java, memory, big-o

I wrote this function as part of interview practice. This method removes a character from a given string.

I was wondering how I could make this code more efficient when it comes to runtime/space. I think my code is O(n) and I'm not sure if I can increase the efficiency. However, perhaps using things such as StringBuffer or StringBuilder would increase it a bit? Not sure as I'm still a bit new to Java.

```
public static String takeOut(String str, char c) {
    int len = str.length();
    String newstr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != c) {
            newstr = newstr + str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: No, this is definitely *not* O(n). Think about what `newstr = newstr + str.charAt(i)` needs to do. Imagine all n characters aren't the one you're looking for. (And yes, StringBuilder is what you're looking for.) See http://yoda.arachsys.com/java/stringbuffer.html - written ages ago, but just replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` everywhere.

Comment: what about `replaceAll()`?

Comment: why not use `str.replaceAll(c+"","")`?

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question to try and not use replaceAll as part of the challenge

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string)

Comment: @mek nope But ill take a look now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java, so your answer actually results in `len` number of strings being created. Which means they are copied `len` times, so you have O(N*N) code here.  StringBuilder is definitely a better approach.

```
public static String takeOut(String str, char c) {
    int len = str.length();
    StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != c) {
            newstr.append((char)str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return newstr.toString();
}
```

A simpler approach would be to use the built in function:

```
public static String takeOut(String str, char c) {
    return str.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
}
```

Comment: I think you need to fix `StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: Yes I do @Liondancer. That's what I get for staying up late and answering stackoverflow questions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` would definitely prevent your code from creating new strings with every iteration. Additionally, is the character to be removed contained only once in the string? Then you could break the `for` loop after the first match. Also, locally store the result of `String#charAt` to not call the method twice.

Comment: multiple times within the string

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
str.replaceAll(c,"");
```

?
Maybe the Java-Runtime kows the fastest way of replacing (deleting)...

Comment: Don't ask a question.. answer it. (find out the stats ur self)

Comment: It will not be efficient at all

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to replace any char more efficiently would be:

1) Convert the `String` to a `char[]` array.

2) Run through the array, testing each `character` one by one and replacing it if needed and append in `StringBuilder`

I think this is probably the fastest performance you will get in pure Java.