# Zero-garbage large String deserialization in Java, Humongous object issue

Tags: java, serialization, garbage-collection, java-8, g1gc

I am looking for a way to deserialize a `String` from a `byte[]` in Java with as little garbage produced as possible. Because I am creating my own serializer and de-serializer, I have complete freedom to implement any solution on the server-side (i.e. when serializing data), and on the client-side (i.e. when de-serializing data).

I have managed to efficiently **serialize** a `String` without incurring any garbage overhead by iterating through the `String's` chars (`String.charAt(i)`) and converting each `char` (16-bit value) to 2x 8-bit value. There is a nice debate regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string). An alternative is to use Reflection to access `String's` underlying `char[]` directly, but this in outside the scope of the problem.

However, it seems impossible for me to deserialize the `byte[]` without creating the `char[]` **twice**, which seems, well, weird.

The procedure:

1. Create `char[]`
2. Iterate through `byte[]` and fill-in the `char[]`
3. Create String with `String(char[])` constructor

Because of Java's `String` immutability rules, the constructor copies the char[], creating 2x GC overhead. I can always use mechanisms to circumvent this (Unsafe `String` allocation + Reflection to set the `char[]` instance), but I just wanted to ask if there are any consequences to this other than me breaking every convention on `String's` immutability.

Of course, the wisest response to this would be "come on, stop doing this and have trust in GC, the original `char[]` will be extremely short-lived and G1 will get rid of it momentarily", which actually makes sense, **if the `char[]` is smaller than 1/2 of the G1's region size**. If it is larger, the char[] will be directly allocated as a humongous object (i.e. automatically propagated outside of the G1's region). Such objects are extremely hard to be efficiently garbage collected in G1. That's why each allocation matters.

Any ideas on how to tackle the issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: have you considered simply not working with Strings and just serializing the raw byte data and doing character set conversions on subsections when it's absolutely necessary?

Comment: I have. My idea was to create a new class `MutableString`, and implement a lot of traditionally garbage-heavy opertations over it (fastpath `String` split, for instance), and then have a method `toString(from, to)` which creates a "view" instance which is of type `String`. I could do that. But this would require to completely refactor our application and to use `MutableString`s everywhere possible. It is a nice idea, but I wanted to explore alternatives first.

Comment: Are you aware that all these things already exist? There are `CharBuffer` and `StringBuilder`, both being a kind of mutable `String` (unless you’ve created an immutable view), there are methods for creating lightweight subsequences of them and they all implement `CharSequence`, the `interface` on which the regex package, which actually implements the `split` operation, works on. And while it *looks like* character contents is copied all the time when converting between `String`s, `CharBuffer`s and `StringBuilder`s when looking at the source code, HotSpot has special optimizations for them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, which is useless, if you have an unmanaged environment.

The `java.lang.String` class has a package-private constructor `String(char[] value, boolean share)`.

Source:

```
/*
* Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
* this constructor is always expected to be called with share==true.
* a separate constructor is needed because we already have a public
* String(char[]) constructor that makes a copy of the given char[].
*/
String(char[] value, boolean share) {
    // assert share : "unshared not supported";
    this.value = value;
}
```

This is being used extensively within Java, e.g. in `Integer.toString()`, `Long.toString()`, `String.concat(String)`, `String.replace(char, char)`, `String.valueOf(char)`.

The solution (or hack, whatever you want to call it) is to move the class to `java.lang` package and to access the package-private constructor. This will not bode well with the security manager, but this can be circumvented.

Comment: instead of moving a class into the package you could probably just access the construcor via reflection and then build a method handle/lambda for the constructor method to avoid calling overheads

Answer (score 4):

> Such objects are extremely hard to be efficiently garbage collected in G1.

This may not be true any longer, but you will have to evaluate it for your own application. JDK Bugs [8027959](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027959) and [8048179](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048179) introduce new mechanisms for collecting humongous, short-lived objects. According to the bug flags you might have to run with jdk versions ≥8u40 and ≥8u60 to reap their respective benefits.

Experimental option of interest:

```
-XX:+G1ReclaimDeadHumongousObjectsAtYoungGC
```

Tracing:

```
-XX:+G1TraceReclaimDeadHumongousObjectsAtYoungGC
```

For further advice and questions regarding those features I would recommend hitting the [hotspot-gc-use](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-gc-use) mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution with simple "secret" native Java library:

```
String longString = StringUtils.repeat("bla", 1000000);
char[] longArray = longString.toCharArray();
String fastCopiedString = SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().newStringUnsafe(longArray);
```