# Switching to G1 gc form CMS

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

Is it advisable to switch from CMS to G1 with large object requests(approx. 40-50MB). 
Available resource details:
Heap Size : Between 6GB-16GB.
Heap region size: 8MB-32MB.
I applied G1 GC with following configurations:
Heap Size: 12GB, Region size: 8MB but due to large no. of Humongous object requests triggers Full GC was triggered(After checking the logs I found out that humongous objects were not getting reclaimed because the initial-mark initiated during humongous allocation never got finished which results in old generation getting completely filled).
Should I stick to G1 or roll back to CMS?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark both GC's with typical stress loads from your application?

Comment: Hey @EricJ. actually a lot of applications are running on my host. I tried CMS there is a lot of fragmentation. To avoid this I switched to G1. I just want to know whether G1 can handle such large request if they come very frequently ?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065423/1362755) for references regarding humongous objects and G1