# StringSortingandIntegerAddition without regular expression

Tags: arrays, string

I have a String array which contains both combination of strings and integers. I need to sort the strings and add the integers at the end. Here is the program I have written. Any optimization would be helpful.

> ```
> import java.io.BufferedReader;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStreamReader;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.List;
>
> public class SortStringandAddIntegerEx {
> public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
> System.out.println("Enter the characters");
> BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
> String input = read.readLine();
> String[] inputArray = { input };
> List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
> String stringChars = "";
> String sortedCharacters = "";
> int sum = 0;
> for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
> stringChars = stringChars + inputArray[i];
> }
> for (int j = 0; j < stringChars.length(); j++) {
> if (Character.isDigit(stringChars.charAt(j))) {
> sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(stringChars.valueOf(stringChars.charAt(j)));
>
> } else {
> sortedCharacters = sortedCharacters + stringChars.charAt(j);
> }
> }
> char[] chars = sortedCharacters.toCharArray();
> Arrays.sort(chars);
> String sorted = new String(chars);
> result.add(sorted + " " + sum);
> for (int k = 0; k < result.size(); k++) {
> System.out.println("Final output is " + result.get(k));
> }
> }
> }
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over your code for a while i cant really see any improvements other than simple syntax to reduce code length, performance wise you really have it covered as without a regex there really is not many other options for finding int's in a string other than testing each character and even the method you used assuming you pass in each line 1 at a time adheres to this performance principle:

> For strings 1 to 256 characters in length, calling string.charAt(i)
>   wins with an average processing of 13.4 million to 588 million
>   characters per second.
>   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894258/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-a-string)
>
> For long strings, 512 to 256K characters length, using reflection to
>   access the String's backing array is fastest. This technique is almost
>   twice as fast as String.charAt(i) (178% faster). The average speed
>   over this range was 1.111 billion characters per second.

The only suggestions i have are for readability:

```
    for (String inputArray1 : inputArray) {
        stringChars = stringChars + inputArray1;
    }
```

Probably isnt any real help since the code seems to utilize best practices. Anyway good luck with your work!

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion I will try the way you have suggested.Thanks