# Foreach loop in Java doesn't work

Tags: java

I am trying to create a for-each loop in Java that iterates on every character in a string. When I try to do this I get an error in NetBeans:

```
for-each not applicable to expression type
required:array or java.lang.Iterable, found java.lang.String
```

This is the Java code on which I get an error:

```
for(char c : fen){
}
```

`fen` is a String

I am trying to understand the source code of a game writen in C# and the foreach loop there worked:

```
foreach(char in fen){}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a

Comment: Ok fine I will admit it.. It's because I wrote that particular par of the compiler... :-(

Answer (score 18):

The compilation error message you get is pretty clear.

For-each loop is applicable for arrays and `Iterable`. 
`String` is not an array. It holds array of characters but it is not an array itself.
`String` does not implement interface `Iterable` too.

If you want to use for-each loop for iteration over characters into the string you have to say:

`for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {}`

Answer (score 2):

String is not iteratable, try [`String#GetBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
for (byte b : str.getBytes(yourCharSet)) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String` is not iteratable. however you can convert `String` to char Array to iterate like this:

```
char[] fen = string.toCharArray();
for(char c : fen){
   //do your work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for-each loop wont work as you expected. For reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

```
char[] fen = //define array here
for(char c : fen){
}
```