# Java Using a stack to reverse the words in a sentence

Tags: java, string, stack

I am supposed to write a code that reads a sentence from the user and prints the characters of the words in the sentence backwards. It should include a helper method that takes a String as a parameter and returns a new String with the characters reversed. The individual words are reversed, for example the sentence "Hi dog cat". would print "iH god tac". I can make the entire sentence reverse but i cant figure out how to reverse individual words. Thanks!   Also, i know how to return the String once i have found it, but i just cant get the right string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ReverseStack 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sentence;

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        sentence = scan.nextLine();

        String k = PrintStack(sentence);
    }

    private static String PrintStack(String sentence)
    {
        String reverse;
        String stringReversed = "";

        Stack<String> stack= new Stack<String>();

        sentence.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(sentence.substring(i, i+1));
        }

        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            stringReversed += stack.pop();
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse is: " + stringReversed);


        return reverse;
    }

}
```

Comment: Being lazy, I'd reverse the order of the words, then read the string from back to front and copy it.

Answer (score 2):

I will type an expatiation so you can still get the experience of writing the code, rather than me just giving you the code.

First create a `Stack` of `Character`s. Then use add each character in the `String` to the `Stack`, starting with the first `char`, then the second, and so on. Now either clear the `String` or create a new `String` to store the reversed word. Finally, add each character from the `Stack` to the `String`. This will pull the last character off first, then the second to last, and so on.

Note: I believe you have to use the `Character` wrapper class, rather than the primitive `char`; I may be incorrect about that though.

If you aren't familiar with how `Stack`s work, here is a nice interactive tool to visualize it: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/JavaVersions/Stacks/AbstractStack/AbstractStack.htm

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
```

to be

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
```

and refactor your methods code as necessary; i.e.

[What is the easiest/best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a different kind of stack, but I suspect this might help

```
private static String reverseWord(String in) {
  if (in.length() < 2) {
    return in;
  }
  return reverseWord(in.substring(1)) + in.substring(0, 1);
}

private static String reverseSentence(String in) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in);
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    if (sb.length() > 0)
      sb.append(' ');
    sb.append(reverseWord(st.nextToken()));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String sentence = "Hi dog cat";
  String expectedOutput = "iH god tac";
  System.out.println(expectedOutput
      .equals(reverseSentence(sentence)));
}
```

Outputs

```
true
```