# String to char[] without String methods

Tags: java, string, character-arrays

I am practicing for interviews and I am given a question to create the String method `indexOf` without the use of string methods. My first thought was to process the String into a `char[]` but I am not sure how to do so without the use of `.toCharArray()`

If anyone has ever had this interview question asked to them I would love your input.

Comment: You can access the backing char array using reflection.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut not quite sure what this means sorry. could you further explain or provide an example

Comment: There's no sensible way.  Unless they meant without using `String` at all - i.e. `int indexOf(char[] str, char[] find)` or similar.  (Which is still not 'sensible', or course.)

Comment: Are you meant to implement that method for an instance of `String` or would the input already be `char[]`? If you get a `String` instance, are you sure you're not allowed to use `toCharArray()`? If that would be the case you're probably also not allowed to call other methods on `String` and thus you'd have to fall back to reflection, which is unsafe since you'd have to dive into the internals of `String`. This would be a really odd question for an interview as Java developer.

Comment: @Paul that was what I thought as well. But I wasnt sure of what inputs I was given

Comment: Can you use the methods of the interface String implements? (CharSequence)

Comment: @Thomas I guess I can try the question with `char[]` as input instead of string

Comment: At a minimum, you would have to have access to the `charAt()` method.

Comment: `String` implements `CharSequence`.  So you could write the method entirely against the abstraction `CharSequence`.  Would that count as not 'using' methods from `String`?

Comment: Could have been worse.  They could have asked you to take a psychometric test.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using *any* method provided by `String` the only option to "convert" a string to a character array would be the use of reflection:

```
char[] c = String.class.getDeclaredField( "value" ).get( "your string" );
```

Note that you'd have to catch exceptions etc.

And a **big note**: this is *very* unsafe, since you never know if the field is called `value` in any implementation. This is not an intended usage of the `String` class. Also note that the resulting array might be bigger than the actual string, i.e. the null termination character might be at any location.

Comment: This helped a lot. I believe that this is the best answer and the interviewer would most likely have the method input as `char[]`

Answer (score 2):

If your input is a `CharSequence`, you can do so like this:

```
CharSequence str = yourString;
char[] chars = new char[str.length()];
for (int i = chars.length; i-->0;) {
     chars[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
//chars now contains the characters of the string
```

Comment: You have used both `length()` and `chatAt()` methods, so I assume not the best answer!

Comment: @tmarwen Well, those are both CharSequence methods, not specific to Strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard one; honestly I don't know.

I wonder of these answers help

[What is the easiest/best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a)

There's one answer which uses `StringCharacterIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int customIndexOf(String string,char character) {
        String c = String.valueOf(character);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(string).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(""));
        int i=0;

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            if (sc.next().equals(c)) {
                return i;
            }
            i++;

        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an utility method that gets access to the `value` instance variable of `String` and returns the first position of a charachter in that string if it exists or **-1** if it does not:

```
public class ReflectedUtils {

  public static final int indexOf(String s, char c)
  {
    int position = -1;
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
        Constructor constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(clazz);
        String ztring = (String) constructor.newInstance(s);
        Field field = ztring.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        char[] chars = (char[]) field.get(ztring);
        for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++)
        {
            if(chars[i] == c)
            {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return position;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(ReflectedUtils.indexOf("Hello", 'e')));
  }
}
```