# Java - what are characters, code points and surrogates? What difference is there between them?

Tags: java, character-encoding, character

I'm trying to find an explanation of the terms "character", "code point" and "surrogate", and while these terms aren't limited to Java, if there are any language-specific differences I'd like the explanation as it relates to Java.

I've found some information about the differences between characters and code points, characters being what is displayed for human users, and code points being a value encoding that specific character, but I have a no idea about surrogates. What are surrogates, and how are they different from characters and code points? Do I have the right definitions for characters and code points?

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a) about stepping through a string as an array of characters, the specific comment that prompted this question was "Note that this technique gives you characters, not code points, meaning you may get surrogates." I didn't really understand, and rather than create a long series of comments on a 5-year-old question I thought it would be best to ask for clarification in a new question.

Comment: All of these answers so far have added more to my understanding of the terms in my question, so while I'm picking one "answer", I think they all helped me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To represent text in computers, you have to solve two things: first, you have to map symbols to numbers, then, you have to represent a sequence of those numbers with bytes.

A [Code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) is a number that identifies a symbol. Two well-known standards for assigning numbers to symbols are ASCII and Unicode. ASCII defines 128 symbols. Unicode currently defines 109384 symbols, that's way more than 2<sup>16</sup>.

Furthermore, ASCII specifies that number sequences are represented one byte per number, while Unicode specifies several possibilities, such as UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.

When you try to use an encoding which uses less bits per character than are needed to represent all possible values (such as UTF-16, which uses 16 bits), you need some workaround.

Thus, [Surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) are 16-bit values that indicate symbols that do not fit into a single two-byte value.

Java uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) internally to represent text.

In particular, a `char` (character) is an unsigned two-byte value that contains a UTF-16 value.

If you want to learn more about Java and Unicode, I can recommend this newsletter: [Part 1](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue209.html), [Part 2](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue211.html)

Comment: And if I remember correctly, 8 bits = 1 byte, so that would put UTF-8 as 1 byte per character, UTF-16 as 2 bytes, and UTF-32 as 4 bytes correct?

Comment: @AliumBritt Not quite so easy. UTF-8/16 are roughly equivalent, different mechanics. UTF-8 is 1-4 bytes with UTF-16 being 2 bytes.

Comment: @AliumBritt UTF-8 and -16 use 1 or 2 bytes when possible, but for the higher code points, using 4 bytes is inevitable.

Comment: @Cephalopod - Nitpick: Strictly speaking a UTF-8 "code point" can be up to 6 bytes ... except that bytes 5 and 6 are only required for "planes" that are outside of the official Unicode codepoint space.  (And they've said they will never go there ...)

Comment: @StephenC I think they could even go to seven bytes, given that there's still [one prefix bit left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). To clarify: with 4 bytes, UTF-8 can encode 2097151 code points, 20 times the number of code points that are currently defined. So 4 bytes won't be exceeded anytime soon.

Comment: I'm wrong.  The definitive UTF-8 spec is Unicode 6.0.0, and it explicitly defines the encoding for the Unicode codepoint range only.  The 5, 6 or even 7 byte forms are non-standard extensions.  (And according to the Wikipedia page, extending to 7 bytes requires using one of the bytes of a BOM ... which would be a bad thing.)

Answer (score 21):

You can find a short explanation in the Javadoc for the class [java.lang.Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):

> **Unicode Character Representations**
>
> The `char` data type (and therefore the value that a `Character` object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal *code points* is now `U+0000` to `U+10FFFF`, known as *Unicode scalar value*. [..]
>
> The set of characters from `U+0000` to `U+FFFF` is sometimes referred to as the *Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)*. Characters whose code points are greater than `U+FFFF` are called *supplementary characters*. The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in `char` arrays and in the `String` and `StringBuffer` classes. In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of `char` values, the first from the *high-surrogates* range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the *low-surrogates* range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).

In other words:

A *code point* usually represents a single *character*. Originally, the values of type `char` matched exactly the Unicode code points. This encoding was also known as [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set).

For that reason, `char` was defined as a 16-Bit type. However, there are currently more than 2^16 *characters* in Unicode. To support the whole *character set*, the encoding was changed from the fixed-length encoding [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) to the variable-length encoding [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Within this encoding, each code point is represented by a single `char` or by two `char`s. In the latter case, the two chars are called a *surrogate pair*.

UTF-16 was defined in such a way, that there is no difference between text encoded with UTF-16 and UCS-2, if all code points are below 2^14. That means, `char` can be used to represent some but not all *characters*. If a *character* can not be represented within a single `char`, the term `char` is misleading, because it is just used as as 16-Bit word.

Answer (score 12):

Code points typically refers to Unicode codepoints.  The Unicode glossary says this:

> [Codepoint(1)](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#code_point): Any value in the Unicode codespace; that is, the range of integers from 0 to 10FFFF16.

In Java, a character (`char`) is an unsigned 16 bit value; i.e 0 to FFFF.

As you can see, there are more Unicode codepoints that can be represented as Java characters.  And yet Java needs to be able to represent text using all valid Unicode codepoints.

The way that Java deals with this is to represent codepoints that are larger than FFFF as a *pair* of characters (code units); i.e. a [surrogate pair](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#surrogate_pair).  These *encode* a Unicode codepoint that is larger than FFFF as a pair of 16 bit values. This uses the fact that a subrange of the Unicode code space (i.e. D800 to U+DFFF) is reserved for representing surrogate pairs.  The technical details are [here](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G2630).

---

The proper term for the encoding that Java is using is the [UTF-16 Encoding Form](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#utf_16_encoding_form).

Another term that you might see is [code unit](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#code_unit) which is the minimum representational unit used in a particular encoding.  In UTF-16 the code unit is 16 bits, which corresponds to a Java `char`.  Other encodings (e.g. UTF-8, ISO 8859-1, etc) have 8 bit code units, and UTF-32 has a 32 bit code unit.

---

The term character has many meanings.  It means all sorts of things in different contexts.  The Unicode glossary gives 4 meanings for [Character](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#character) as follows:

> Character. (1) The smallest component of written language that has semantic value; refers to the abstract meaning and/or shape, rather than a specific shape (see also glyph), though in code tables some form of visual representation is essential for the reader’s understanding.
>
> Character. (2) Synonym for abstract character.  ([Abstract Character](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#abstract_character). A unit of information used for the organization, control, or representation of textual data.)
>
> Character. (3) The basic unit of encoding for the Unicode character encoding.
>
> Character. (4) The English name for the ideographic written elements of Chinese origin. [See ideograph (2).]

And then there is the Java specific meaning for character; i.e. a 16 bit signed number (of type `char`) that *may or may not* represent a complete or partial Unicode codepoint in UTF-16 encoding.

Answer (score 6):

To begin with, unicode is a standard which tries to define and map all individual characters from all languages, from english letters to chinese, numbers, symbols etc.

Basically unicode has long list of numbered characters where the *code point* refers to the numbering.

In short

- *Characters* are the individual tokens in a text, whether letter, number or symbol.
- A *code point* refers to numbering of a token in the unicode standard
- Characters represented using the `UTF-16` encoding scheme houses so many characters that all does not fit in the alotted space of single a java character.
- [*Surrogate pairs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) is the term used to say that one character needs to be represented in the space of a pair of characters. *Surrogate pairs* is the term used to say that one character is listed so high in the unicode table it needs a pair of character spaces to represent it.

Comment: In that case, would "surrogate" as I phrased it be equivalent to "surrogate pair", since there would always be two if I wanted the representation of character?

Answer (score 5):

Simply put:

- `Code unit` is `char` that takes 2 byte, encoded as `UTF-16`, each char not necessarily represent a `real world character`.
- `Code point` is always a `real world character`, it may contain 1 or 2 `Code unit`, see it as an `int`, that may take 4 bytes.

---

Let the code (test case) tell the truth:
(need Java **9**+, due to String's method `codePoints()` and `chars()`)

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String s = "Hi, 你好, おはよう, α-Ω\uD834\uDD1E"; // last real character is "", that takes 2 code unit,
    assertEquals(s.length(), s.toCharArray().length); // length() is based on char (aka code unit), not code point,

    System.out.printf("input string:\t\"%s\"%n%n", s);

    System.out.println("------ as code point (aka. real character) ------");
    // code point,
    s.codePoints().forEach(cp -> System.out.println(Character.toChars(cp)));
    assertEquals(s.codePoints().count(), s.length() - 1); // last read character takes 2 unit code,
    assertEquals(s.codePoints().count(), s.codePointCount(0, s.length())); // there is a method codePointCount() on String to get code point count on given char range,

    System.out.println("\n------ as char (aka. code unit) ------");
    // chars (aka. code unit),
    s.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println(Character.toChars(c)));
    assertEquals(s.chars().count(), s.length()); // string length is the count of code unit, not code point,
}
```

Output:

```
input string:   "Hi, 你好, おはよう, α-Ω"

------ as code point (aka. real character) ------
H
i
,
 
你
好
,
 
お
は
よ
う
,
 
α
-
Ω


------ as char (aka. code unit) ------
H
i
,
 
你
好
,
 
お
は
よ
う
,
 
α
-
Ω
?
?
```

The last real character is , it takes 2 code unit `\uD834\uDD1E`, and it's a single `code point`, when try to print the 2 code unit separately, they can't be recognized, and shows `?` for each.