# how does 'length' work to return the length of a String type array object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, string-length

we have length()-  **a method** that returns the length of a String object,

for example:

```
 String s, sarr[] = {"a","b"};  
 System.out.println(s.length());  
 System.out.println(sarr.length);
```

in Java. But what does happen, in background, in case of String type array object that we have to use **length** , probably a parameter, that returns the length of that said array object?

Comment: It does what it says on the tin. It returns the number of characters in the String. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size, and the size is available in their length read-only attribute. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html.

Comment: The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Comment: Go to the source code: it has an array of chars that is created at the beginning, after that, `length()` only returns the lenght of that array

Comment: @morgano thanks. I was about to unjar the rt.jar file to check it myself. none's answer make a sense. regret!!

Comment: @AmirHasan did my answer help you? If yes, simply mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every array in Java has a field `length`. On the other hand, `String` has `private final char value[];` field which has it's length.

Method `length()` of `String` returns the `length` of the `value`.

The length of `value` is `final` so there is no danger of public field being vandalized.

Answer (score 1):

The String **class** has a method [length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) where (quoting):

*The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.*

Any array in Java has a field `length`; and that field simply represents the number of elements in that array.

So, if you are really interested in what Java strings do, you have to dive into all those "[unicode details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979676/java-what-are-characters-code-points-and-surrogates-what-difference-is-there)".

Comment: Your answer would have made more sense without the bizarre formatting, and the final part about 'that Unicode stuff' makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, updated my answer.