# Count occurrences and remove duplicates from a String

Tags: java, duplicates, find-occurrences

So I am building a huffman tree and I am in need of taking a String as input, and then create 2 arrays containing each letter and the number of occurrences of that letter in the original string, like this:

```
String s = "mississippi"
```

Should result in:

```
char[] charArr = {'m','i', 's', 'p'};
int[] count = {1,4,4,2};
```

There are alot of question regarding this and alot of examples on how to solve this, especially here on stackoverflow but the only one that I managed to get working was this:

```
private void findOccurences(String s) {
        List<Character> original = new ArrayList<Character>(s.length());
        List<Character> duplicateRemoved;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            original.add(s.charAt(i));
        }
        duplicateRemoved = new ArrayList<Character>(original);

        // Remove duplicates from second list.
        Set<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
        hs.addAll(duplicateRemoved);
        duplicateRemoved.clear();
        duplicateRemoved.addAll(hs);

        charFreqs = new int[duplicateRemoved.size()];
        charArr = new char[duplicateRemoved.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
            char c = duplicateRemoved.get(i);
            int count = Collections.frequency(original, c);
            charArr[i] = c;
            charFreqs[i] = count;
        }
    }
```

But it feels very cumberstone and it also scrambles the order of the letters in the array. If I use this my resulting array is as follows:

```
char[] charArr = {'p','s', 'i', 'm'};
```

Are there any better way to do what I want?

Comment: Use a HashMap and try if it suits your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I will do it this way

```
String s = "mississippi";
List<String> original = Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> duplicateRemoved = Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                      .distinct()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
ArrayList<Integer> Occurrences = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 1;

for (String aList : duplicateRemoved) {
    counter = (int) original.stream().filter(s1 -> s1.equals(aList)).count();
            Occurrences.add(counter);
        }
System.out.println(duplicateRemoved);
System.out.println(Occurrences);
```

and the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Navnath Jadhav";
Function<Map<Character, Long>, Map<Character, Long>> filterDuplicates = (m) -> m.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

final Map<Character, Long> collect = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(
        collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(c -> c, LinkedHashMap::new, counting()),
                filterDuplicates
        )
);
```

Using Java 8 :

1. `chars()` method of String returns us [surrogate code point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23979676/6099811) of each character in String
2. Using [mapToObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) map those code point to character `c -> (char) c`
3. using [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [Collectors.counting()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) we will calculate occurrences of each character in string
4. After counting occurrences we want to remove duplicate characters.[collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) help us to do some computation on the final result, It accepts first parameter as Collector so we will provide groupingBy and second parameter as a Function which accepts result generated by groupingBy and returns new result

   Function<Map<Character, Long>, Map<Character, Long>>
   This function will drop characters which are duplicate and only allow character which has occurred only once `filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)`

*If you don't want to preserve order of character then you can remove `LinkedHashMap`, So it will be like `toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)` and `groupingBy(c -> c, counting())`

[Demo](https://www.online-java.com/jzUVSmX16C)