# whatsapp shares whatsapp://send?text=content_here

Tags: android

i am using below code to share content from my android app which shows webview page to whatsapp.

it works just fine except one issues.
it shares complete link including whatsapp://send?text=
i want only content to be shared.

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""  + uri);
 sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
 sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 startActivity(sendIntent);
```

i tried using replace for replacing the whatsapp://send?text but it gives error that replace(string,string) is undefined.

is there any better way to achieve this

Comment: what is exactly you want to share?

Comment: @VulovicVukasin <a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=Hum to tere dil ki mahfil sajane aye thay,&lt;br /&gt;  teri kasam tujhy apna banany aye thay.&lt;br /&gt;  kis bat ki saza di tu ne ham ko,&lt;br /&gt;  bewafa hum to tere dard ko apnany aye thay&hellip;&lt;br /&gt;  " data-action="share/whatsapp/share" ><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>

Comment: @VulovicVukasin content after whatsapp://send?text=

Comment: and that is the string uri?

Comment: @VulovicVukasin yes string uri is full string including whatsapp://send?text=

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, you need to go one char by char until you get to the char "?".Create a loop and go character by character. When you get to the "?" leave the loop, and select the rest of the string as a new string.
[What is the easiest/best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a)

After that, your strin is from charAt(where the "?" is + 1) to the end.

Comment: you have the tutorial and the idea, create it yourself.

Comment: its giving error The method charAt(int) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)