# How can I get characters in string using index but did not use charAt()?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java. They say to not use `String` functions - so how can I get characters in a `String` using the index but **not using `charAt()`**?

other question has answer but they all are using charAt()

I also want to get characters one by one using a loop.

Comment: are you using a 1, 0 enter keyboard? tell us what can you use?

Comment: you can also refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way not to use any `String` methods with `java.text.CharacterIterator` but you are not using indexes as  well. I am not sure if this complies with your question.

```
CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(yourString);
for(char c = it.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = it.next()) {
  // do whatever you want with c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(yourString);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i)
    System.out.println(sb.charAt(i));
```

Comment: thanks for answer . but i want it did not use charAt().

Comment: @Tom @supunrajasinghe guys, this code *DOES NOT USE* `String.charAt()`. It uses `StringBuilder.charAt()` which is -technically- a different method.