# Which loop which is best for iterating for strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I always use normal for loop ie.

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){}
```

for iterating through string although its simple way to iterate through string can anyone suggest me other type of looping method which is more efficent and short syntax that could make code more clean and readable.

Thanks for help Btw i am new to online community.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        
}
```

I always use this method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care? If you need to search or manipulate each character of the String as char, then what you're doing is fine. Your code always depends on the requirements of the job, so there's no "best" way. Resist the temptation to make unnecessary optimizations. If your code isn't doing what you need it to do in the way it needs to be done, then explore alternatives.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach. It's been common in Java for decades, and is easily recognized and  understood. It may be there are circumstances that would make one of the alternatives better. But, since we don't know those circumstances, we couldn't say.

Comment: There aren't many alternatives, to be honest. There's `CharacterIterator` and its implementation `StringCharacterIterator` but that's cumbersome. There's using `toCharArray()` but that creates a copy. There's `getChars` but that either requires a full copy, or a partial copy and nested looping (outer loop for `getChars`, inner loop for the `char[]` that's been read). And if you feel like doing things even more overly complex, there's `StringReader`. But in the end, out of all of these, the simple loop with `charAt` is still preferred.

Comment: There is one alternative that actually is interesting though, and that's using `chars()`. That returns an `IntStream` so you need to cast its arguments to `char` before adding them to any `StringBuilder` etc., otherwise you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest/best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a)

Comment: @RobSpoor has a point while I was iterating through string was using `char [] arr=s.toCharArray();` which creates a copy is there any possible solution that could iterate through string without using extra memory (I mean without converting to into char array) P.S I am aware String objects are immutable.

Comment: @SatishChauhan the code you posted originally is just fine, and has the least overhead in memory of all solutions I can think of.

Comment: So basically my question is the solution And one of the best practices that could be followed for iterating for strings in Java?

Comment: Your first example is not legal Java if `s` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of looping String, some of the options could be:

```
//Using For Each loop
String str = "Hello, World!";
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    // Process or print the character 'c'
}

//Using Java streams
String str = "Hello, World!";
str.chars().forEach(c -> {
    // Process or print the character 'c'
});
```